# I need list of all class name of Font-Awesome

Tags: css, font-awesome

I build app that will present a lot of icons so I need list of all Font-Awesome class name like
 `["fa-dropbox","fa-rocket","fa-globe", ....]`
so on is there any way to get it ?

Comment: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/css/font-awesome.css

Comment: There's no way to programatically get them, look at the overview posted above.

Comment: This is a better cheat sheet http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Comment: @Adeneo—a program could get all the style rules and extract all the class name to get all the classes used in style sheets. It could also get all elements in the document and extract their class values via the *className* property to see those in use. Not necessarily efficient but *possible*. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - sure, it's probably theorethically possible, but there's no easy way to do it, and one shouldn't need to. The stylesheets for FA contains hundreds of classes, not all of them for icons, some invert colors, rotate fonts and do other things, but the OP is asking for "all" classnames, so I guess that would be fine ?

Comment: you can use jQuery selector in this site to find all https://ohmycheatsheet.com/fontawesome/

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/cheatsheet/

Answer (score 103, accepted):

***April 2017 edit: Updated to 4.7.0***

As linked in the comments on your question, Font Awesome provides a [*Cheatsheet* page](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) which lists all icon previews, class names and character codes and even lists aliases (`fa-automobile`, for instance, which is an alias of `fa-car`).

- 4.*.* Cheatsheet: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet
- 3.2.1 Cheatsheet: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/cheatsheet

There are a total of 593 icon class names (including aliases) in version 4.3.0. Here is the list in the format you desire (including aliases, but with no " (alias)" comments):

```
["fa-500px", "fa-address-book", "fa-address-book-o", "fa-address-card", "fa-address-card-o", "fa-adjust", "fa-adn", "fa-align-center", "fa-align-justify", "fa-align-left", "fa-align-right", "fa-amazon", "fa-ambulance", "fa-american-sign-language-interpreting", "fa-anchor", "fa-android", "fa-angellist", "fa-angle-double-down", "fa-angle-double-left", "fa-angle-double-right", "fa-angle-double-up", "fa-angle-down", "fa-angle-left", "fa-angle-right", "fa-angle-up", "fa-apple", "fa-archive", "fa-area-chart", "fa-arrow-circle-down", "fa-arrow-circle-left", "fa-arrow-circle-o-down", "fa-arrow-circle-o-left", "fa-arrow-circle-o-right", "fa-arrow-circle-o-up", "fa-arrow-circle-right", "fa-arrow-circle-up", "fa-arrow-down", "fa-arrow-left", "fa-arrow-right", "fa-arrow-up", "fa-arrows", "fa-arrows-alt", "fa-arrows-h", "fa-arrows-v", "fa-asl-interpreting", "fa-assistive-listening-systems", "fa-asterisk", "fa-at", "fa-audio-description", "fa-automobile", "fa-backward", "fa-balance-scale", "fa-ban", "fa-bandcamp", "fa-bank", "fa-bar-chart", "fa-bar-chart-o", "fa-barcode", "fa-bars", "fa-bath", "fa-bathtub", "fa-battery", "fa-battery-0", "fa-battery-1", "fa-battery-2", "fa-battery-3", "fa-battery-4", "fa-battery-empty", "fa-battery-full", "fa-battery-half", "fa-battery-quarter", "fa-battery-three-quarters", "fa-bed", "fa-beer", "fa-behance", "fa-behance-square", "fa-bell", "fa-bell-o", "fa-bell-slash", "fa-bell-slash-o", "fa-bicycle", "fa-binoculars", "fa-birthday-cake", "fa-bitbucket", "fa-bitbucket-square", "fa-bitcoin", "fa-black-tie", "fa-blind", "fa-bluetooth", "fa-bluetooth-b", "fa-bold", "fa-bolt", "fa-bomb", "fa-book", "fa-bookmark", "fa-bookmark-o", "fa-braille", "fa-briefcase", "fa-btc", "fa-bug", "fa-building", "fa-building-o", "fa-bullhorn", "fa-bullseye", "fa-bus", "fa-buysellads", "fa-cab", "fa-calculator", "fa-calendar", "fa-calendar-check-o", "fa-calendar-minus-o", "fa-calendar-o", "fa-calendar-plus-o", "fa-calendar-times-o", "fa-camera", "fa-camera-retro", "fa-car", "fa-caret-down", "fa-caret-left", "fa-caret-right", "fa-caret-square-o-down", "fa-caret-square-o-left", "fa-caret-square-o-right", "fa-caret-square-o-up", "fa-caret-up", "fa-cart-arrow-down", "fa-cart-plus", "fa-cc", "fa-cc-amex", "fa-cc-diners-club", "fa-cc-discover", "fa-cc-jcb", "fa-cc-mastercard", "fa-cc-paypal", "fa-cc-stripe", "fa-cc-visa", "fa-certificate", "fa-chain", "fa-chain-broken", "fa-check", "fa-check-circle", "fa-check-circle-o", "fa-check-square", "fa-check-square-o", "fa-chevron-circle-down", "fa-chevron-circle-left", "fa-chevron-circle-right", "fa-chevron-circle-up", "fa-chevron-down", "fa-chevron-left", "fa-chevron-right", "fa-chevron-up", "fa-child", "fa-chrome", "fa-circle", "fa-circle-o", "fa-circle-o-notch", "fa-circle-thin", "fa-clipboard", "fa-clock-o", "fa-clone", "fa-close", "fa-cloud", "fa-cloud-download", "fa-cloud-upload", "fa-cny", "fa-code", "fa-code-fork", "fa-codepen", "fa-codiepie", "fa-coffee", "fa-cog", "fa-cogs", "fa-columns", "fa-comment", "fa-comment-o", "fa-commenting", "fa-commenting-o", "fa-comments", "fa-comments-o", "fa-compass", "fa-compress", "fa-connectdevelop", "fa-contao", "fa-copy", "fa-copyright", "fa-creative-commons", "fa-credit-card", "fa-credit-card-alt", "fa-crop", "fa-crosshairs", "fa-css3", "fa-cube", "fa-cubes", "fa-cut", "fa-cutlery", "fa-dashboard", "fa-dashcube", "fa-database", "fa-deaf", "fa-deafness", "fa-dedent", "fa-delicious", "fa-desktop", "fa-deviantart", "fa-diamond", "fa-digg", "fa-dollar", "fa-dot-circle-o", "fa-download", "fa-dribbble", "fa-drivers-license", "fa-drivers-license-o", "fa-dropbox", "fa-drupal", "fa-edge", "fa-edit", "fa-eercast", "fa-eject", "fa-ellipsis-h", "fa-ellipsis-v", "fa-empire", "fa-envelope", "fa-envelope-o", "fa-envelope-open", "fa-envelope-open-o", "fa-envelope-square", "fa-envira", "fa-eraser", "fa-etsy", "fa-eur", "fa-euro", "fa-exchange", "fa-exclamation", "fa-exclamation-circle", "fa-exclamation-triangle", "fa-expand", "fa-expeditedssl", "fa-external-link", "fa-external-link-square", "fa-eye", "fa-eye-slash", "fa-eyedropper", "fa-fa", "fa-facebook", "fa-facebook-f", "fa-facebook-official", "fa-facebook-square", "fa-fast-backward", "fa-fast-forward", "fa-fax", "fa-feed", "fa-female", "fa-fighter-jet", "fa-file", "fa-file-archive-o", "fa-file-audio-o", "fa-file-code-o", "fa-file-excel-o", "fa-file-image-o", "fa-file-movie-o", "fa-file-o", "fa-file-pdf-o", "fa-file-photo-o", "fa-file-picture-o", "fa-file-powerpoint-o", "fa-file-sound-o", "fa-file-text", "fa-file-text-o", "fa-file-video-o", "fa-file-word-o", "fa-file-zip-o", "fa-files-o", "fa-film", "fa-filter", "fa-fire", "fa-fire-extinguisher", "fa-firefox", "fa-first-order", "fa-flag", "fa-flag-checkered", "fa-flag-o", "fa-flash", "fa-flask", "fa-flickr", "fa-floppy-o", "fa-folder", "fa-folder-o", "fa-folder-open", "fa-folder-open-o", "fa-font", "fa-font-awesome", "fa-fonticons", "fa-fort-awesome", "fa-forumbee", "fa-forward", "fa-foursquare", "fa-free-code-camp", "fa-frown-o", "fa-futbol-o", "fa-gamepad", "fa-gavel", "fa-gbp", "fa-ge", "fa-gear", "fa-gears", "fa-genderless", "fa-get-pocket", "fa-gg", "fa-gg-circle", "fa-gift", "fa-git", "fa-git-square", "fa-github", "fa-github-alt", "fa-github-square", "fa-gitlab", "fa-gittip", "fa-glass", "fa-glide", "fa-glide-g", "fa-globe", "fa-google", "fa-google-plus", "fa-google-plus-circle", "fa-google-plus-official", "fa-google-plus-square", "fa-google-wallet", "fa-graduation-cap", "fa-gratipay", "fa-grav", "fa-group", "fa-h-square", "fa-hacker-news", "fa-hand-grab-o", "fa-hand-lizard-o", "fa-hand-o-down", "fa-hand-o-left", "fa-hand-o-right", "fa-hand-o-up", "fa-hand-paper-o", "fa-hand-peace-o", "fa-hand-pointer-o", "fa-hand-rock-o", "fa-hand-scissors-o", "fa-hand-spock-o", "fa-hand-stop-o", "fa-handshake-o", "fa-hard-of-hearing", "fa-hashtag", "fa-hdd-o", "fa-header", "fa-headphones", "fa-heart", "fa-heart-o", "fa-heartbeat", "fa-history", "fa-home", "fa-hospital-o", "fa-hotel", "fa-hourglass", "fa-hourglass-1", "fa-hourglass-2", "fa-hourglass-3", "fa-hourglass-end", "fa-hourglass-half", "fa-hourglass-o", "fa-hourglass-start", "fa-houzz", "fa-html5", "fa-i-cursor", "fa-id-badge", "fa-id-card", "fa-id-card-o", "fa-ils", "fa-image", "fa-imdb", "fa-inbox", "fa-indent", "fa-industry", "fa-info", "fa-info-circle", "fa-inr", "fa-instagram", "fa-institution", "fa-internet-explorer", "fa-intersex", "fa-ioxhost", "fa-italic", "fa-joomla", "fa-jpy", "fa-jsfiddle", "fa-key", "fa-keyboard-o", "fa-krw", "fa-language", "fa-laptop", "fa-lastfm", "fa-lastfm-square", "fa-leaf", "fa-leanpub", "fa-legal", "fa-lemon-o", "fa-level-down", "fa-level-up", "fa-life-bouy", "fa-life-buoy", "fa-life-ring", "fa-life-saver", "fa-lightbulb-o", "fa-line-chart", "fa-link", "fa-linkedin", "fa-linkedin-square", "fa-linode", "fa-linux", "fa-list", "fa-list-alt", "fa-list-ol", "fa-list-ul", "fa-location-arrow", "fa-lock", "fa-long-arrow-down", "fa-long-arrow-left", "fa-long-arrow-right", "fa-long-arrow-up", "fa-low-vision", "fa-magic", "fa-magnet", "fa-mail-forward", "fa-mail-reply", "fa-mail-reply-all", "fa-male", "fa-map", "fa-map-marker", "fa-map-o", "fa-map-pin", "fa-map-signs", "fa-mars", "fa-mars-double", "fa-mars-stroke", "fa-mars-stroke-h", "fa-mars-stroke-v", "fa-maxcdn", "fa-meanpath", "fa-medium", "fa-medkit", "fa-meetup", "fa-meh-o", "fa-mercury", "fa-microchip", "fa-microphone", "fa-microphone-slash", "fa-minus", "fa-minus-circle", "fa-minus-square", "fa-minus-square-o", "fa-mixcloud", "fa-mobile", "fa-mobile-phone", "fa-modx", "fa-money", "fa-moon-o", "fa-mortar-board", "fa-motorcycle", "fa-mouse-pointer", "fa-music", "fa-navicon", "fa-neuter", "fa-newspaper-o", "fa-object-group", "fa-object-ungroup", "fa-odnoklassniki", "fa-odnoklassniki-square", "fa-opencart", "fa-openid", "fa-opera", "fa-optin-monster", "fa-outdent", "fa-pagelines", "fa-paint-brush", "fa-paper-plane", "fa-paper-plane-o", "fa-paperclip", "fa-paragraph", "fa-paste", "fa-pause", "fa-pause-circle", "fa-pause-circle-o", "fa-paw", "fa-paypal", "fa-pencil", "fa-pencil-square", "fa-pencil-square-o", "fa-percent", "fa-phone", "fa-phone-square", "fa-photo", "fa-picture-o", "fa-pie-chart", "fa-pied-piper", "fa-pied-piper-alt", "fa-pied-piper-pp", "fa-pinterest", "fa-pinterest-p", "fa-pinterest-square", "fa-plane", "fa-play", "fa-play-circle", "fa-play-circle-o", "fa-plug", "fa-plus", "fa-plus-circle", "fa-plus-square", "fa-plus-square-o", "fa-podcast", "fa-power-off", "fa-print", "fa-product-hunt", "fa-puzzle-piece", "fa-qq", "fa-qrcode", "fa-question", "fa-question-circle", "fa-question-circle-o", "fa-quora", "fa-quote-left", "fa-quote-right", "fa-ra", "fa-random", "fa-ravelry", "fa-rebel", "fa-recycle", "fa-reddit", "fa-reddit-alien", "fa-reddit-square", "fa-refresh", "fa-registered", "fa-remove", "fa-renren", "fa-reorder", "fa-repeat", "fa-reply", "fa-reply-all", "fa-resistance", "fa-retweet", "fa-rmb", "fa-road", "fa-rocket", "fa-rotate-left", "fa-rotate-right", "fa-rouble", "fa-rss", "fa-rss-square", "fa-rub", "fa-ruble", "fa-rupee", "fa-s15", "fa-safari", "fa-save", "fa-scissors", "fa-scribd", "fa-search", "fa-search-minus", "fa-search-plus", "fa-sellsy", "fa-send", "fa-send-o", "fa-server", "fa-share", "fa-share-alt", "fa-share-alt-square", "fa-share-square", "fa-share-square-o", "fa-shekel", "fa-sheqel", "fa-shield", "fa-ship", "fa-shirtsinbulk", "fa-shopping-bag", "fa-shopping-basket", "fa-shopping-cart", "fa-shower", "fa-sign-in", "fa-sign-language", "fa-sign-out", "fa-signal", "fa-signing", "fa-simplybuilt", "fa-sitemap", "fa-skyatlas", "fa-skype", "fa-slack", "fa-sliders", "fa-slideshare", "fa-smile-o", "fa-snapchat", "fa-snapchat-ghost", "fa-snapchat-square", "fa-snowflake-o", "fa-soccer-ball-o", "fa-sort", "fa-sort-alpha-asc", "fa-sort-alpha-desc", "fa-sort-amount-asc", "fa-sort-amount-desc", "fa-sort-asc", "fa-sort-desc", "fa-sort-down", "fa-sort-numeric-asc", "fa-sort-numeric-desc", "fa-sort-up", "fa-soundcloud", "fa-space-shuttle", "fa-spinner", "fa-spoon", "fa-spotify", "fa-square", "fa-square-o", "fa-stack-exchange", "fa-stack-overflow", "fa-star", "fa-star-half", "fa-star-half-empty", "fa-star-half-full", "fa-star-half-o", "fa-star-o", "fa-steam", "fa-steam-square", "fa-step-backward", "fa-step-forward", "fa-stethoscope", "fa-sticky-note", "fa-sticky-note-o", "fa-stop", "fa-stop-circle", "fa-stop-circle-o", "fa-street-view", "fa-strikethrough", "fa-stumbleupon", "fa-stumbleupon-circle", "fa-subscript", "fa-subway", "fa-suitcase", "fa-sun-o", "fa-superpowers", "fa-superscript", "fa-support", "fa-table", "fa-tablet", "fa-tachometer", "fa-tag", "fa-tags", "fa-tasks", "fa-taxi", "fa-telegram", "fa-television", "fa-tencent-weibo", "fa-terminal", "fa-text-height", "fa-text-width", "fa-th", "fa-th-large", "fa-th-list", "fa-themeisle", "fa-thermometer", "fa-thermometer-0", "fa-thermometer-1", "fa-thermometer-2", "fa-thermometer-3", "fa-thermometer-4", "fa-thermometer-empty", "fa-thermometer-full", "fa-thermometer-half", "fa-thermometer-quarter", "fa-thermometer-three-quarters", "fa-thumb-tack", "fa-thumbs-down", "fa-thumbs-o-down", "fa-thumbs-o-up", "fa-thumbs-up", "fa-ticket", "fa-times", "fa-times-circle", "fa-times-circle-o", "fa-times-rectangle", "fa-times-rectangle-o", "fa-tint", "fa-toggle-down", "fa-toggle-left", "fa-toggle-off", "fa-toggle-on", "fa-toggle-right", "fa-toggle-up", "fa-trademark", "fa-train", "fa-transgender", "fa-transgender-alt", "fa-trash", "fa-trash-o", "fa-tree", "fa-trello", "fa-tripadvisor", "fa-trophy", "fa-truck", "fa-try", "fa-tty", "fa-tumblr", "fa-tumblr-square", "fa-turkish-lira", "fa-tv", "fa-twitch", "fa-twitter", "fa-twitter-square", "fa-umbrella", "fa-underline", "fa-undo", "fa-universal-access", "fa-university", "fa-unlink", "fa-unlock", "fa-unlock-alt", "fa-unsorted", "fa-upload", "fa-usb", "fa-usd", "fa-user", "fa-user-circle", "fa-user-circle-o", "fa-user-md", "fa-user-o", "fa-user-plus", "fa-user-secret", "fa-user-times", "fa-users", "fa-vcard", "fa-vcard-o", "fa-venus", "fa-venus-double", "fa-venus-mars", "fa-viacoin", "fa-viadeo", "fa-viadeo-square", "fa-video-camera", "fa-vimeo", "fa-vimeo-square", "fa-vine", "fa-vk", "fa-volume-control-phone", "fa-volume-down", "fa-volume-off", "fa-volume-up", "fa-warning", "fa-wechat", "fa-weibo", "fa-weixin", "fa-whatsapp", "fa-wheelchair", "fa-wheelchair-alt", "fa-wifi", "fa-wikipedia-w", "fa-window-close", "fa-window-close-o", "fa-window-maximize", "fa-window-minimize", "fa-window-restore", "fa-windows", "fa-won", "fa-wordpress", "fa-wpbeginner", "fa-wpexplorer", "fa-wpforms", "fa-wrench", "fa-xing", "fa-xing-square", "fa-y-combinator", "fa-y-combinator-square", "fa-yahoo", "fa-yc", "fa-yc-square", "fa-yelp", "fa-yen", "fa-yoast", "fa-youtube", "fa-youtube-play", "fa-youtube-square"]
```

And here is the full list of version 4.3 icon class names, including aliases, as a list:

```
fa-500px
fa-address-book
fa-address-book-o
fa-address-card
fa-address-card-o
fa-adjust
fa-adn
fa-align-center
fa-align-justify
fa-align-left
fa-align-right
fa-amazon
fa-ambulance
fa-american-sign-language-interpreting
fa-anchor
fa-android
fa-angellist
fa-angle-double-down
fa-angle-double-left
fa-angle-double-right
fa-angle-double-up
fa-angle-down
fa-angle-left
fa-angle-right
fa-angle-up
fa-apple
fa-archive
fa-area-chart
fa-arrow-circle-down
fa-arrow-circle-left
fa-arrow-circle-o-down
fa-arrow-circle-o-left
fa-arrow-circle-o-right
fa-arrow-circle-o-up
fa-arrow-circle-right
fa-arrow-circle-up
fa-arrow-down
fa-arrow-left
fa-arrow-right
fa-arrow-up
fa-arrows
fa-arrows-alt
fa-arrows-h
fa-arrows-v
fa-asl-interpreting
fa-assistive-listening-systems
fa-asterisk
fa-at
fa-audio-description
fa-automobile
fa-backward
fa-balance-scale
fa-ban
fa-bandcamp
fa-bank
fa-bar-chart
fa-bar-chart-o
fa-barcode
fa-bars
fa-bath
fa-bathtub
fa-battery
fa-battery-0
fa-battery-1
fa-battery-2
fa-battery-3
fa-battery-4
fa-battery-empty
fa-battery-full
fa-battery-half
fa-battery-quarter
fa-battery-three-quarters
fa-bed
fa-beer
fa-behance
fa-behance-square
fa-bell
fa-bell-o
fa-bell-slash
fa-bell-slash-o
fa-bicycle
fa-binoculars
fa-birthday-cake
fa-bitbucket
fa-bitbucket-square
fa-bitcoin
fa-black-tie
fa-blind
fa-bluetooth
fa-bluetooth-b
fa-bold
fa-bolt
fa-bomb
fa-book
fa-bookmark
fa-bookmark-o
fa-braille
fa-briefcase
fa-btc
fa-bug
fa-building
fa-building-o
fa-bullhorn
fa-bullseye
fa-bus
fa-buysellads
fa-cab
fa-calculator
fa-calendar
fa-calendar-check-o
fa-calendar-minus-o
fa-calendar-o
fa-calendar-plus-o
fa-calendar-times-o
fa-camera
fa-camera-retro
fa-car
fa-caret-down
fa-caret-left
fa-caret-right
fa-caret-square-o-down
fa-caret-square-o-left
fa-caret-square-o-right
fa-caret-square-o-up
fa-caret-up
fa-cart-arrow-down
fa-cart-plus
fa-cc
fa-cc-amex
fa-cc-diners-club
fa-cc-discover
fa-cc-jcb
fa-cc-mastercard
fa-cc-paypal
fa-cc-stripe
fa-cc-visa
fa-certificate
fa-chain
fa-chain-broken
fa-check
fa-check-circle
fa-check-circle-o
fa-check-square
fa-check-square-o
fa-chevron-circle-down
fa-chevron-circle-left
fa-chevron-circle-right
fa-chevron-circle-up
fa-chevron-down
fa-chevron-left
fa-chevron-right
fa-chevron-up
fa-child
fa-chrome
fa-circle
fa-circle-o
fa-circle-o-notch
fa-circle-thin
fa-clipboard
fa-clock-o
fa-clone
fa-close
fa-cloud
fa-cloud-download
fa-cloud-upload
fa-cny
fa-code
fa-code-fork
fa-codepen
fa-codiepie
fa-coffee
fa-cog
fa-cogs
fa-columns
fa-comment
fa-comment-o
fa-commenting
fa-commenting-o
fa-comments
fa-comments-o
fa-compass
fa-compress
fa-connectdevelop
fa-contao
fa-copy
fa-copyright
fa-creative-commons
fa-credit-card
fa-credit-card-alt
fa-crop
fa-crosshairs
fa-css3
fa-cube
fa-cubes
fa-cut
fa-cutlery
fa-dashboard
fa-dashcube
fa-database
fa-deaf
fa-deafness
fa-dedent
fa-delicious
fa-desktop
fa-deviantart
fa-diamond
fa-digg
fa-dollar
fa-dot-circle-o
fa-download
fa-dribbble
fa-drivers-license
fa-drivers-license-o
fa-dropbox
fa-drupal
fa-edge
fa-edit
fa-eercast
fa-eject
fa-ellipsis-h
fa-ellipsis-v
fa-empire
fa-envelope
fa-envelope-o
fa-envelope-open
fa-envelope-open-o
fa-envelope-square
fa-envira
fa-eraser
fa-etsy
fa-eur
fa-euro
fa-exchange
fa-exclamation
fa-exclamation-circle
fa-exclamation-triangle
fa-expand
fa-expeditedssl
fa-external-link
fa-external-link-square
fa-eye
fa-eye-slash
fa-eyedropper
fa-fa
fa-facebook
fa-facebook-f
fa-facebook-official
fa-facebook-square
fa-fast-backward
fa-fast-forward
fa-fax
fa-feed
fa-female
fa-fighter-jet
fa-file
fa-file-archive-o
fa-file-audio-o
fa-file-code-o
fa-file-excel-o
fa-file-image-o
fa-file-movie-o
fa-file-o
fa-file-pdf-o
fa-file-photo-o
fa-file-picture-o
fa-file-powerpoint-o
fa-file-sound-o
fa-file-text
fa-file-text-o
fa-file-video-o
fa-file-word-o
fa-file-zip-o
fa-files-o
fa-film
fa-filter
fa-fire
fa-fire-extinguisher
fa-firefox
fa-first-order
fa-flag
fa-flag-checkered
fa-flag-o
fa-flash
fa-flask
fa-flickr
fa-floppy-o
fa-folder
fa-folder-o
fa-folder-open
fa-folder-open-o
fa-font
fa-font-awesome
fa-fonticons
fa-fort-awesome
fa-forumbee
fa-forward
fa-foursquare
fa-free-code-camp
fa-frown-o
fa-futbol-o
fa-gamepad
fa-gavel
fa-gbp
fa-ge
fa-gear
fa-gears
fa-genderless
fa-get-pocket
fa-gg
fa-gg-circle
fa-gift
fa-git
fa-git-square
fa-github
fa-github-alt
fa-github-square
fa-gitlab
fa-gittip
fa-glass
fa-glide
fa-glide-g
fa-globe
fa-google
fa-google-plus
fa-google-plus-circle
fa-google-plus-official
fa-google-plus-square
fa-google-wallet
fa-graduation-cap
fa-gratipay
fa-grav
fa-group
fa-h-square
fa-hacker-news
fa-hand-grab-o
fa-hand-lizard-o
fa-hand-o-down
fa-hand-o-left
fa-hand-o-right
fa-hand-o-up
fa-hand-paper-o
fa-hand-peace-o
fa-hand-pointer-o
fa-hand-rock-o
fa-hand-scissors-o
fa-hand-spock-o
fa-hand-stop-o
fa-handshake-o
fa-hard-of-hearing
fa-hashtag
fa-hdd-o
fa-header
fa-headphones
fa-heart
fa-heart-o
fa-heartbeat
fa-history
fa-home
fa-hospital-o
fa-hotel
fa-hourglass
fa-hourglass-1
fa-hourglass-2
fa-hourglass-3
fa-hourglass-end
fa-hourglass-half
fa-hourglass-o
fa-hourglass-start
fa-houzz
fa-html5
fa-i-cursor
fa-id-badge
fa-id-card
fa-id-card-o
fa-ils
fa-image
fa-imdb
fa-inbox
fa-indent
fa-industry
fa-info
fa-info-circle
fa-inr
fa-instagram
fa-institution
fa-internet-explorer
fa-intersex
fa-ioxhost
fa-italic
fa-joomla
fa-jpy
fa-jsfiddle
fa-key
fa-keyboard-o
fa-krw
fa-language
fa-laptop
fa-lastfm
fa-lastfm-square
fa-leaf
fa-leanpub
fa-legal
fa-lemon-o
fa-level-down
fa-level-up
fa-life-bouy
fa-life-buoy
fa-life-ring
fa-life-saver
fa-lightbulb-o
fa-line-chart
fa-link
fa-linkedin
fa-linkedin-square
fa-linode
fa-linux
fa-list
fa-list-alt
fa-list-ol
fa-list-ul
fa-location-arrow
fa-lock
fa-long-arrow-down
fa-long-arrow-left
fa-long-arrow-right
fa-long-arrow-up
fa-low-vision
fa-magic
fa-magnet
fa-mail-forward
fa-mail-reply
fa-mail-reply-all
fa-male
fa-map
fa-map-marker
fa-map-o
fa-map-pin
fa-map-signs
fa-mars
fa-mars-double
fa-mars-stroke
fa-mars-stroke-h
fa-mars-stroke-v
fa-maxcdn
fa-meanpath
fa-medium
fa-medkit
fa-meetup
fa-meh-o
fa-mercury
fa-microchip
fa-microphone
fa-microphone-slash
fa-minus
fa-minus-circle
fa-minus-square
fa-minus-square-o
fa-mixcloud
fa-mobile
fa-mobile-phone
fa-modx
fa-money
fa-moon-o
fa-mortar-board
fa-motorcycle
fa-mouse-pointer
fa-music
fa-navicon
fa-neuter
fa-newspaper-o
fa-object-group
fa-object-ungroup
fa-odnoklassniki
fa-odnoklassniki-square
fa-opencart
fa-openid
fa-opera
fa-optin-monster
fa-outdent
fa-pagelines
fa-paint-brush
fa-paper-plane
fa-paper-plane-o
fa-paperclip
fa-paragraph
fa-paste
fa-pause
fa-pause-circle
fa-pause-circle-o
fa-paw
fa-paypal
fa-pencil
fa-pencil-square
fa-pencil-square-o
fa-percent
fa-phone
fa-phone-square
fa-photo
fa-picture-o
fa-pie-chart
fa-pied-piper
fa-pied-piper-alt
fa-pied-piper-pp
fa-pinterest
fa-pinterest-p
fa-pinterest-square
fa-plane
fa-play
fa-play-circle
fa-play-circle-o
fa-plug
fa-plus
fa-plus-circle
fa-plus-square
fa-plus-square-o
fa-podcast
fa-power-off
fa-print
fa-product-hunt
fa-puzzle-piece
fa-qq
fa-qrcode
fa-question
fa-question-circle
fa-question-circle-o
fa-quora
fa-quote-left
fa-quote-right
fa-ra
fa-random
fa-ravelry
fa-rebel
fa-recycle
fa-reddit
fa-reddit-alien
fa-reddit-square
fa-refresh
fa-registered
fa-remove
fa-renren
fa-reorder
fa-repeat
fa-reply
fa-reply-all
fa-resistance
fa-retweet
fa-rmb
fa-road
fa-rocket
fa-rotate-left
fa-rotate-right
fa-rouble
fa-rss
fa-rss-square
fa-rub
fa-ruble
fa-rupee
fa-s15
fa-safari
fa-save
fa-scissors
fa-scribd
fa-search
fa-search-minus
fa-search-plus
fa-sellsy
fa-send
fa-send-o
fa-server
fa-share
fa-share-alt
fa-share-alt-square
fa-share-square
fa-share-square-o
fa-shekel
fa-sheqel
fa-shield
fa-ship
fa-shirtsinbulk
fa-shopping-bag
fa-shopping-basket
fa-shopping-cart
fa-shower
fa-sign-in
fa-sign-language
fa-sign-out
fa-signal
fa-signing
fa-simplybuilt
fa-sitemap
fa-skyatlas
fa-skype
fa-slack
fa-sliders
fa-slideshare
fa-smile-o
fa-snapchat
fa-snapchat-ghost
fa-snapchat-square
fa-snowflake-o
fa-soccer-ball-o
fa-sort
fa-sort-alpha-asc
fa-sort-alpha-desc
fa-sort-amount-asc
fa-sort-amount-desc
fa-sort-asc
fa-sort-desc
fa-sort-down
fa-sort-numeric-asc
fa-sort-numeric-desc
fa-sort-up
fa-soundcloud
fa-space-shuttle
fa-spinner
fa-spoon
fa-spotify
fa-square
fa-square-o
fa-stack-exchange
fa-stack-overflow
fa-star
fa-star-half
fa-star-half-empty
fa-star-half-full
fa-star-half-o
fa-star-o
fa-steam
fa-steam-square
fa-step-backward
fa-step-forward
fa-stethoscope
fa-sticky-note
fa-sticky-note-o
fa-stop
fa-stop-circle
fa-stop-circle-o
fa-street-view
fa-strikethrough
fa-stumbleupon
fa-stumbleupon-circle
fa-subscript
fa-subway
fa-suitcase
fa-sun-o
fa-superpowers
fa-superscript
fa-support
fa-table
fa-tablet
fa-tachometer
fa-tag
fa-tags
fa-tasks
fa-taxi
fa-telegram
fa-television
fa-tencent-weibo
fa-terminal
fa-text-height
fa-text-width
fa-th
fa-th-large
fa-th-list
fa-themeisle
fa-thermometer
fa-thermometer-0
fa-thermometer-1
fa-thermometer-2
fa-thermometer-3
fa-thermometer-4
fa-thermometer-empty
fa-thermometer-full
fa-thermometer-half
fa-thermometer-quarter
fa-thermometer-three-quarters
fa-thumb-tack
fa-thumbs-down
fa-thumbs-o-down
fa-thumbs-o-up
fa-thumbs-up
fa-ticket
fa-times
fa-times-circle
fa-times-circle-o
fa-times-rectangle
fa-times-rectangle-o
fa-tint
fa-toggle-down
fa-toggle-left
fa-toggle-off
fa-toggle-on
fa-toggle-right
fa-toggle-up
fa-trademark
fa-train
fa-transgender
fa-transgender-alt
fa-trash
fa-trash-o
fa-tree
fa-trello
fa-tripadvisor
fa-trophy
fa-truck
fa-try
fa-tty
fa-tumblr
fa-tumblr-square
fa-turkish-lira
fa-tv
fa-twitch
fa-twitter
fa-twitter-square
fa-umbrella
fa-underline
fa-undo
fa-universal-access
fa-university
fa-unlink
fa-unlock
fa-unlock-alt
fa-unsorted
fa-upload
fa-usb
fa-usd
fa-user
fa-user-circle
fa-user-circle-o
fa-user-md
fa-user-o
fa-user-plus
fa-user-secret
fa-user-times
fa-users
fa-vcard
fa-vcard-o
fa-venus
fa-venus-double
fa-venus-mars
fa-viacoin
fa-viadeo
fa-viadeo-square
fa-video-camera
fa-vimeo
fa-vimeo-square
fa-vine
fa-vk
fa-volume-control-phone
fa-volume-down
fa-volume-off
fa-volume-up
fa-warning
fa-wechat
fa-weibo
fa-weixin
fa-whatsapp
fa-wheelchair
fa-wheelchair-alt
fa-wifi
fa-wikipedia-w
fa-window-close
fa-window-close-o
fa-window-maximize
fa-window-minimize
fa-window-restore
fa-windows
fa-won
fa-wordpress
fa-wpbeginner
fa-wpexplorer
fa-wpforms
fa-wrench
fa-xing
fa-xing-square
fa-y-combinator
fa-y-combinator-square
fa-yahoo
fa-yc
fa-yc-square
fa-yelp
fa-yen
fa-yoast
fa-youtube
fa-youtube-play
fa-youtube-square
```

Comment: can you tell me how you go that list, stripping this from the webpage cheatsheet has many new hex chars, and I need an updated list

Comment: @aggie it was extracted from the cheatsheet with the hex codes filtered out. I've updated the answer to include all the 4.3.0 classes. :)

Comment: you can use jQuery selector in this site to find all https://ohmycheatsheet.com/fontawesome

Comment: Here is the list of all pro icons if you need, https://gist.github.com/cptiwari20/0fb100e26fef5292fc2cd0024d9cd4f5

Comment: Are FA attributes, such as fa-w-14, dynamic? Can they randomly change with a build deployment?

Answer (score 86):

Another little script for posterity.

***Update 02/2018 (version 5.x)***

Latest working version, based on edit from **Blasius Secondus** (thanks).

Open the fonts cheat sheet and run the following snippet in the developper console:
https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet

```
var names = new Set();
var icons = document.getElementsByClassName('icon');
for (const icon of icons) {
  const name = icon.getElementsByTagName('dd')[0].innerText;
  names.add(name);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(names)));
```

**If you want them sorted by section (solid/regular/brand):**

```
var groups = {};
var sections = document.getElementsByClassName('cheatsheet-set');
for (const section of sections) {
  const names = [];
  groups[section.id] = names;
  var icons = section.getElementsByClassName('icon');
  for (const icon of icons) {
    const name = icon.getElementsByTagName('dd')[0].innerText;
    names.push(name);
  }
}
console.log(groups); // Feel free to stringify/manipulate
```

---

***Original answer***

Simply open the latest cheatsheet: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Then in your browser, open the developer console and run:

```
var names = [];
$('.row .col-md-4').each(function() {
  var s = $(this).text();
  var m = s.match(/fa-.*/);
  if (m && m[0] && s.indexOf('(alias)') < 0) {
    names.push(m[0]);
  }
});
console.log( JSON.stringify( names ) );
```

If you want the list instead of an array, replace the last line by

```
console.log( names.join(' ') );
```

(You can use any separator you want instead of space ' ')

The advantage of this method is that **you will only get the visual icons (not the fa-spin and friends), and not the duplicate aliases**.

Comment: @floribon is it possible to get them by type like solid, regular or brands ?

Comment: @soniamaklouf great idea (these didn't exist when I initially wrote my answer), I've added a paragraph with the code to do so.

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: If you want to access pro icons, use this link: https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet/pro/light

Answer (score 22):

Better yet, you can make use of the yml file containing the icon name, its unicode and even its keywords:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/src/icons.yml

Then just use the js-yaml parser and thats it!

```
$.get('https://rawgit.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/src/icons.yml', function(data){    
    var parsedYaml = jsyaml.load(data);
    var body = $('body');

    $.each(parsedYaml.icons, function(index, icon){
        body.append('<i class="fa fa-' + icon.id + '"></i>');
    })
});
```

[Reproduction online](https://jsfiddle.net/and40qhm/)

With a bit more of work you can even categorize icons or even create a search box for them based on their keywords.

### Update 2020:

This can now be found in .json here:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/metadata

Answer (score 19):

First load all icons from [font awesome 5 icons](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=free). 
[image]

now go to developer console and paste following code

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('i')
var icons = [];
nodes.forEach(a => icons.push( a.getAttribute('class') ) )
copy(icons)
```

all font awesome icons now copied in your clipboard.

Answer (score 17):

A very, very easy and handy way to dynamically get all FA icon classes, if you are using `npm` and `@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core` npm package (tested at least with version v1.2.x), is the following:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

// You need to add the entire icon set
library.add(fas)

let fasArray = Object.keys(library.definitions.fas)
```

With just few lines of code, you'll get an array of all icon classes in `solid` library, with values like:

```
[ "ad", "address-book", "address-card", "adjust", "air-freshener", "align-center", "align-justify", "align-left", "align-right", "allergies", "ambulance", "american-sign-language-interpreting", "anchor" ....]
```

For all (`solid` + `regular` + `brand`) icon libraries, you can instead use:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

// Add both three icon sets
library.add(fas, far, fab)

let fasArray = Object.keys(library.definitions.fas)
let farArray = Object.keys(library.definitions.far)
let fabArray = Object.keys(library.definitions.fab)
```

With these arrays, you can build whatever JSON or object structure you want to fit your purpose.

One note to mention, `library.definitions` property seems to not be an official way to get access to all icons in the package, so maybe in future package versions, this snippet might not work; however a quick look at the package's source, it seems somehow unlikely they might replace it, at least without a major restructuring and different versioning.

A second note is that, if you want the array to be dynamic, you have to import the entire icon sets, which might not be something you'd like to do. Otherwise, you can run it once, get the results and use them statically.

Comment: With fontawesome 5 this is still working.

I had to replace the import with 
import { FaIconLibrary } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

And in my constructor I had to add library: FaIconLibrary  but I'm not sure if this was maybe specific for my project or not.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a list of all free Font Awesome icons class names v5.0.1

```
{
"name":"Font Awesome v5.0.1", 
"icons":[
"fab fa-500px",
"fab fa-accessible-icon",
"fab fa-accusoft",
"fas fa-address-book", "far fa-address-book",
"fas fa-address-card", "far fa-address-card",
"fas fa-adjust",
"fab fa-adn",
"fab fa-adversal",
"fab fa-affiliatetheme",
"fab fa-algolia",
"fas fa-align-center",
"fas fa-align-justify",
"fas fa-align-left",
"fas fa-align-right",
"fab fa-amazon",
"fas fa-ambulance",
"fas fa-american-sign-language-interpreting",
"fab fa-amilia",
"fas fa-anchor",
"fab fa-android",
"fab fa-angellist",
"fas fa-angle-double-down",
"fas fa-angle-double-left",
"fas fa-angle-double-right",
"fas fa-angle-double-up",
"fas fa-angle-down",
"fas fa-angle-left",
"fas fa-angle-right",
"fas fa-angle-up",
"fab fa-angrycreative",
"fab fa-angular",
"fab fa-app-store",
"fab fa-app-store-ios",
"fab fa-apper",
"fab fa-apple",
"fab fa-apple-pay",
"fas fa-archive",
"fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-down", "far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down",
"fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left", "far fa-arrow-alt-circle-left",
"fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right", "far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right",
"fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-up", "far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up",
"fas fa-arrow-circle-down",
"fas fa-arrow-circle-left",
"fas fa-arrow-circle-right",
"fas fa-arrow-circle-up",
"fas fa-arrow-down",
"fas fa-arrow-left",
"fas fa-arrow-right",
"fas fa-arrow-up",
"fas fa-arrows-alt",
"fas fa-arrows-alt-h",
"fas fa-arrows-alt-v",
"fas fa-assistive-listening-systems",
"fas fa-asterisk",
"fab fa-asymmetrik",
"fas fa-at",
"fab fa-audible",
"fas fa-audio-description",
"fab fa-autoprefixer",
"fab fa-avianex",
"fab fa-aviato",
"fab fa-aws",
"fas fa-backward",
"fas fa-balance-scale",
"fas fa-ban",
"fab fa-bandcamp",
"fas fa-barcode",
"fas fa-bars",
"fas fa-bath",
"fas fa-battery-empty",
"fas fa-battery-full",
"fas fa-battery-half",
"fas fa-battery-quarter",
"fas fa-battery-three-quarters",
"fas fa-bed",
"fas fa-beer",
"fab fa-behance",
"fab fa-behance-square",
"fas fa-bell", "far fa-bell",
"fas fa-bell-slash", "far fa-bell-slash",
"fas fa-bicycle",
"fab fa-bimobject",
"fas fa-binoculars",
"fas fa-birthday-cake",
"fab fa-bitbucket",
"fab fa-bitcoin",
"fab fa-bity",
"fab fa-black-tie",
"fab fa-blackberry",
"fas fa-blind",
"fab fa-blogger",
"fab fa-blogger-b",
"fab fa-bluetooth",
"fab fa-bluetooth-b",
"fas fa-bold",
"fas fa-bolt",
"fas fa-bomb",
"fas fa-book",
"fas fa-bookmark", "far fa-bookmark",
"fas fa-braille",
"fas fa-briefcase",
"fab fa-btc",
"fas fa-bug",
"fas fa-building", "far fa-building",
"fas fa-bullhorn",
"fas fa-bullseye",
"fab fa-buromobelexperte",
"fas fa-bus",
"fab fa-buysellads",
"fas fa-calculator",
"fas fa-calendar", "far fa-calendar",
"fas fa-calendar-alt", "far fa-calendar-alt",
"fas fa-calendar-check", "far fa-calendar-check",
"fas fa-calendar-minus", "far fa-calendar-minus",
"fas fa-calendar-plus", "far fa-calendar-plus",
"fas fa-calendar-times", "far fa-calendar-times",
"fas fa-camera",
"fas fa-camera-retro",
"fas fa-car",
"fas fa-caret-down",
"fas fa-caret-left",
"fas fa-caret-right",
"fas fa-caret-square-down", "far fa-caret-square-down",
"fas fa-caret-square-left", "far fa-caret-square-left",
"fas fa-caret-square-right", "far fa-caret-square-right",
"fas fa-caret-square-up", "far fa-caret-square-up",
"fas fa-caret-up",
"fas fa-cart-arrow-down",
"fas fa-cart-plus",
"fab fa-cc-amex",
"fab fa-cc-apple-pay",
"fab fa-cc-diners-club",
"fab fa-cc-discover",
"fab fa-cc-jcb",
"fab fa-cc-mastercard",
"fab fa-cc-paypal",
"fab fa-cc-stripe",
"fab fa-cc-visa",
"fab fa-centercode",
"fas fa-certificate",
"fas fa-chart-area",
"fas fa-chart-bar", "far fa-chart-bar",
"fas fa-chart-line",
"fas fa-chart-pie",
"fas fa-check",
"fas fa-check-circle", "far fa-check-circle",
"fas fa-check-square", "far fa-check-square",
"fas fa-chevron-circle-down",
"fas fa-chevron-circle-left",
"fas fa-chevron-circle-right",
"fas fa-chevron-circle-up",
"fas fa-chevron-down",
"fas fa-chevron-left",
"fas fa-chevron-right",
"fas fa-chevron-up",
"fas fa-child",
"fab fa-chrome",
"fas fa-circle", "far fa-circle",
"fas fa-circle-notch",
"fas fa-clipboard", "far fa-clipboard",
"fas fa-clock", "far fa-clock",
"fas fa-clone", "far fa-clone",
"fas fa-closed-captioning", "far fa-closed-captioning",
"fas fa-cloud",
"fas fa-cloud-download-alt",
"fas fa-cloud-upload-alt",
"fab fa-cloudscale",
"fab fa-cloudsmith",
"fab fa-cloudversify",
"fas fa-code",
"fas fa-code-branch",
"fab fa-codepen",
"fab fa-codiepie",
"fas fa-coffee",
"fas fa-cog",
"fas fa-cogs",
"fas fa-columns",
"fas fa-comment", "far fa-comment",
"fas fa-comment-alt", "far fa-comment-alt",
"fas fa-comments", "far fa-comments",
"fas fa-compass", "far fa-compass",
"fas fa-compress",
"fab fa-connectdevelop",
"fab fa-contao",
"fas fa-copy", "far fa-copy",
"fas fa-copyright", "far fa-copyright",
"fab fa-cpanel",
"fab fa-creative-commons",
"fas fa-credit-card", "far fa-credit-card",
"fas fa-crop",
"fas fa-crosshairs",
"fab fa-css3",
"fab fa-css3-alt",
"fas fa-cube",
"fas fa-cubes",
"fas fa-cut",
"fab fa-cuttlefish",
"fab fa-d-and-d",
"fab fa-dashcube",
"fas fa-database",
"fas fa-deaf",
"fab fa-delicious",
"fab fa-deploydog",
"fab fa-deskpro",
"fas fa-desktop",
"fab fa-deviantart",
"fab fa-digg",
"fab fa-digital-ocean",
"fab fa-discord",
"fab fa-discourse",
"fab fa-dochub",
"fab fa-docker",
"fas fa-dollar-sign",
"fas fa-dot-circle", "far fa-dot-circle",
"fas fa-download",
"fab fa-draft2digital",
"fab fa-dribbble",
"fab fa-dribbble-square",
"fab fa-dropbox",
"fab fa-drupal",
"fab fa-dyalog",
"fab fa-earlybirds",
"fab fa-edge",
"fas fa-edit", "far fa-edit",
"fas fa-eject",
"fas fa-ellipsis-h",
"fas fa-ellipsis-v",
"fab fa-ember",
"fab fa-empire",
"fas fa-envelope", "far fa-envelope",
"fas fa-envelope-open", "far fa-envelope-open",
"fas fa-envelope-square",
"fab fa-envira",
"fas fa-eraser",
"fab fa-erlang",
"fab fa-etsy",
"fas fa-euro-sign",
"fas fa-exchange-alt",
"fas fa-exclamation",
"fas fa-exclamation-circle",
"fas fa-exclamation-triangle",
"fas fa-expand",
"fas fa-expand-arrows-alt",
"fab fa-expeditedssl",
"fas fa-external-link-alt",
"fas fa-external-link-square-alt",
"fas fa-eye",
"fas fa-eye-dropper",
"fas fa-eye-slash", "far fa-eye-slash",
"fab fa-facebook",
"fab fa-facebook-f",
"fab fa-facebook-messenger",
"fab fa-facebook-square",
"fas fa-fast-backward",
"fas fa-fast-forward",
"fas fa-fax",
"fas fa-female",
"fas fa-fighter-jet",
"fas fa-file", "far fa-file",
"fas fa-file-alt", "far fa-file-alt",
"fas fa-file-archive", "far fa-file-archive",
"fas fa-file-audio", "far fa-file-audio",
"fas fa-file-code", "far fa-file-code",
"fas fa-file-excel", "far fa-file-excel",
"fas fa-file-image", "far fa-file-image",
"fas fa-file-pdf", "far fa-file-pdf",
"fas fa-file-powerpoint", "far fa-file-powerpoint",
"fas fa-file-video", "far fa-file-video",
"fas fa-file-word", "far fa-file-word",
"fas fa-film",
"fas fa-filter",
"fas fa-fire",
"fas fa-fire-extinguisher",
"fab fa-firefox",
"fab fa-first-order",
"fab fa-firstdraft",
"fas fa-flag", "far fa-flag",
"fas fa-flag-checkered",
"fas fa-flask",
"fab fa-flickr",
"fab fa-fly",
"fas fa-folder", "far fa-folder",
"fas fa-folder-open", "far fa-folder-open",
"fas fa-font",
"fab fa-font-awesome",
"fab fa-font-awesome-alt",
"fab fa-font-awesome-flag",
"fab fa-fonticons",
"fab fa-fonticons-fi",
"fab fa-fort-awesome",
"fab fa-fort-awesome-alt",
"fab fa-forumbee",
"fas fa-forward",
"fab fa-foursquare",
"fab fa-free-code-camp",
"fab fa-freebsd",
"fas fa-frown", "far fa-frown",
"fas fa-futbol", "far fa-futbol",
"fas fa-gamepad",
"fas fa-gavel",
"fas fa-gem", "far fa-gem",
"fas fa-genderless",
"fab fa-get-pocket",
"fab fa-gg",
"fab fa-gg-circle",
"fas fa-gift",
"fab fa-git",
"fab fa-git-square",
"fab fa-github",
"fab fa-github-alt",
"fab fa-github-square",
"fab fa-gitkraken",
"fab fa-gitlab",
"fab fa-gitter",
"fas fa-glass-martini",
"fab fa-glide",
"fab fa-glide-g",
"fas fa-globe",
"fab fa-gofore",
"fab fa-goodreads",
"fab fa-goodreads-g",
"fab fa-google",
"fab fa-google-drive",
"fab fa-google-play",
"fab fa-google-plus",
"fab fa-google-plus-g",
"fab fa-google-plus-square",
"fab fa-google-wallet",
"fas fa-graduation-cap",
"fab fa-gratipay",
"fab fa-grav",
"fab fa-gripfire",
"fab fa-grunt",
"fab fa-gulp",
"fas fa-h-square",
"fab fa-hacker-news",
"fab fa-hacker-news-square",
"fas fa-hand-lizard", "far fa-hand-lizard",
"fas fa-hand-paper", "far fa-hand-paper",
"fas fa-hand-peace", "far fa-hand-peace",
"fas fa-hand-point-down", "far fa-hand-point-down",
"fas fa-hand-point-left", "far fa-hand-point-left",
"fas fa-hand-point-right", "far fa-hand-point-right",
"fas fa-hand-point-up", "far fa-hand-point-up",
"fas fa-hand-pointer", "far fa-hand-pointer",
"fas fa-hand-rock", "far fa-hand-rock",
"fas fa-hand-scissors", "far fa-hand-scissors",
"fas fa-hand-spock", "far fa-hand-spock",
"fas fa-handshake", "far fa-handshake",
"fas fa-hashtag",
"fas fa-hdd", "far fa-hdd",
"fas fa-heading",
"fas fa-headphones",
"fas fa-heart", "far fa-heart",
"fas fa-heartbeat",
"fab fa-hire-a-helper",
"fas fa-history",
"fas fa-home",
"fab fa-hooli",
"fas fa-hospital", "far fa-hospital",
"fab fa-hotjar",
"fas fa-hourglass", "far fa-hourglass",
"fas fa-hourglass-end",
"fas fa-hourglass-half",
"fas fa-hourglass-start",
"fab fa-houzz",
"fab fa-html5",
"fab fa-hubspot",
"fas fa-i-cursor",
"fas fa-id-badge", "far fa-id-badge",
"fas fa-id-card", "far fa-id-card",
"fas fa-image", "far fa-image",
"fas fa-images", "far fa-images",
"fab fa-imdb",
"fas fa-inbox",
"fas fa-indent",
"fas fa-industry",
"fas fa-info",
"fas fa-info-circle",
"fab fa-instagram",
"fab fa-internet-explorer",
"fab fa-ioxhost",
"fas fa-italic",
"fab fa-itunes",
"fab fa-itunes-note",
"fab fa-jenkins",
"fab fa-joget",
"fab fa-joomla",
"fab fa-js",
"fab fa-js-square",
"fab fa-jsfiddle",
"fas fa-key",
"fas fa-keyboard", "far fa-keyboard",
"fab fa-keycdn",
"fab fa-kickstarter",
"fab fa-kickstarter-k",
"fas fa-language",
"fas fa-laptop",
"fab fa-laravel",
"fab fa-lastfm",
"fab fa-lastfm-square",
"fas fa-leaf",
"fab fa-leanpub",
"fas fa-lemon", "far fa-lemon",
"fab fa-less",
"fas fa-level-down-alt",
"fas fa-level-up-alt",
"fas fa-life-ring", "far fa-life-ring",
"fas fa-lightbulb", "far fa-lightbulb",
"fab fa-line",
"fas fa-link",
"fab fa-linkedin",
"fab fa-linkedin-in",
"fab fa-linode",
"fab fa-linux",
"fas fa-lira-sign",
"fas fa-list",
"fas fa-list-alt", "far fa-list-alt",
"fas fa-list-ol",
"fas fa-list-ul",
"fas fa-location-arrow",
"fas fa-lock",
"fas fa-lock-open",
"fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down",
"fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left",
"fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right",
"fas fa-long-arrow-alt-up",
"fas fa-low-vision",
"fab fa-lyft",
"fab fa-magento",
"fas fa-magic",
"fas fa-magnet",
"fas fa-male",
"fas fa-map", "far fa-map",
"fas fa-map-marker",
"fas fa-map-marker-alt",
"fas fa-map-pin",
"fas fa-map-signs",
"fas fa-mars",
"fas fa-mars-double",
"fas fa-mars-stroke",
"fas fa-mars-stroke-h",
"fas fa-mars-stroke-v",
"fab fa-maxcdn",
"fab fa-medapps",
"fab fa-medium",
"fab fa-medium-m",
"fas fa-medkit",
"fab fa-medrt",
"fab fa-meetup",
"fas fa-meh", "far fa-meh",
"fas fa-mercury",
"fas fa-microchip",
"fas fa-microphone",
"fas fa-microphone-slash",
"fab fa-microsoft",
"fas fa-minus",
"fas fa-minus-circle",
"fas fa-minus-square", "far fa-minus-square",
"fab fa-mix",
"fab fa-mixcloud",
"fab fa-mizuni",
"fas fa-mobile",
"fas fa-mobile-alt",
"fab fa-modx",
"fab fa-monero",
"fas fa-money-bill-alt", "far fa-money-bill-alt",
"fas fa-moon", "far fa-moon",
"fas fa-motorcycle",
"fas fa-mouse-pointer",
"fas fa-music",
"fab fa-napster",
"fas fa-neuter",
"fas fa-newspaper", "far fa-newspaper",
"fab fa-nintendo-switch",
"fab fa-node",
"fab fa-node-js",
"fab fa-npm",
"fab fa-ns8",
"fab fa-nutritionix",
"fas fa-object-group", "far fa-object-group",
"fas fa-object-ungroup", "far fa-object-ungroup",
"fab fa-odnoklassniki",
"fab fa-odnoklassniki-square",
"fab fa-opencart",
"fab fa-openid",
"fab fa-opera",
"fab fa-optin-monster",
"fab fa-osi",
"fas fa-outdent",
"fab fa-page4",
"fab fa-pagelines",
"fas fa-paint-brush",
"fab fa-palfed",
"fas fa-paper-plane", "far fa-paper-plane",
"fas fa-paperclip",
"fas fa-paragraph",
"fas fa-paste",
"fab fa-patreon",
"fas fa-pause",
"fas fa-pause-circle", "far fa-pause-circle",
"fas fa-paw",
"fab fa-paypal",
"fas fa-pen-square",
"fas fa-pencil-alt",
"fas fa-percent",
"fab fa-periscope",
"fab fa-phabricator",
"fab fa-phoenix-framework",
"fas fa-phone",
"fas fa-phone-square",
"fas fa-phone-volume",
"fab fa-pied-piper",
"fab fa-pied-piper-alt",
"fab fa-pied-piper-pp",
"fab fa-pinterest",
"fab fa-pinterest-p",
"fab fa-pinterest-square",
"fas fa-plane",
"fas fa-play",
"fas fa-play-circle", "far fa-play-circle",
"fab fa-playstation",
"fas fa-plug",
"fas fa-plus",
"fas fa-plus-circle",
"fas fa-plus-square", "far fa-plus-square",
"fas fa-podcast",
"fas fa-pound-sign",
"fas fa-power-off",
"fas fa-print",
"fab fa-product-hunt",
"fab fa-pushed",
"fas fa-puzzle-piece",
"fab fa-python",
"fab fa-qq",
"fas fa-qrcode",
"fas fa-question",
"fas fa-question-circle", "far fa-question-circle",
"fab fa-quora",
"fas fa-quote-left",
"fas fa-quote-right",
"fas fa-random",
"fab fa-ravelry",
"fab fa-react",
"fab fa-rebel",
"fas fa-recycle",
"fab fa-red-river",
"fab fa-reddit",
"fab fa-reddit-alien",
"fab fa-reddit-square",
"fas fa-redo",
"fas fa-redo-alt",
"fas fa-registered", "far fa-registered",
"fab fa-rendact",
"fab fa-renren",
"fas fa-reply",
"fas fa-reply-all",
"fab fa-replyd",
"fab fa-resolving",
"fas fa-retweet",
"fas fa-road",
"fas fa-rocket",
"fab fa-rocketchat",
"fab fa-rockrms",
"fas fa-rss",
"fas fa-rss-square",
"fas fa-ruble-sign",
"fas fa-rupee-sign",
"fab fa-safari",
"fab fa-sass",
"fas fa-save", "far fa-save",
"fab fa-schlix",
"fab fa-scribd",
"fas fa-search",
"fas fa-search-minus",
"fas fa-search-plus",
"fab fa-searchengin",
"fab fa-sellcast",
"fab fa-sellsy",
"fas fa-server",
"fab fa-servicestack",
"fas fa-share",
"fas fa-share-alt",
"fas fa-share-alt-square",
"fas fa-share-square", "far fa-share-square",
"fas fa-shekel-sign",
"fas fa-shield-alt",
"fas fa-ship",
"fab fa-shirtsinbulk",
"fas fa-shopping-bag",
"fas fa-shopping-basket",
"fas fa-shopping-cart",
"fas fa-shower",
"fas fa-sign-in-alt",
"fas fa-sign-language",
"fas fa-sign-out-alt",
"fas fa-signal",
"fab fa-simplybuilt",
"fab fa-sistrix",
"fas fa-sitemap",
"fab fa-skyatlas",
"fab fa-skype",
"fab fa-slack",
"fab fa-slack-hash",
"fas fa-sliders-h",
"fab fa-slideshare",
"fas fa-smile", "far fa-smile",
"fab fa-snapchat",
"fab fa-snapchat-ghost",
"fab fa-snapchat-square",
"fas fa-snowflake", "far fa-snowflake",
"fas fa-sort",
"fas fa-sort-alpha-down",
"fas fa-sort-alpha-up",
"fas fa-sort-amount-down",
"fas fa-sort-amount-up",
"fas fa-sort-down",
"fas fa-sort-numeric-down",
"fas fa-sort-numeric-up",
"fas fa-sort-up",
"fab fa-soundcloud",
"fas fa-space-shuttle",
"fab fa-speakap",
"fas fa-spinner",
"fab fa-spotify",
"fas fa-square", "far fa-square",
"fab fa-stack-exchange",
"fab fa-stack-overflow",
"fas fa-star", "far fa-star",
"fas fa-star-half", "far fa-star-half",
"fab fa-staylinked",
"fab fa-steam",
"fab fa-steam-square",
"fab fa-steam-symbol",
"fas fa-step-backward",
"fas fa-step-forward",
"fas fa-stethoscope",
"fab fa-sticker-mule",
"fas fa-sticky-note", "far fa-sticky-note",
"fas fa-stop",
"fas fa-stop-circle", "far fa-stop-circle",
"fab fa-strava",
"fas fa-street-view",
"fas fa-strikethrough",
"fab fa-stripe",
"fab fa-stripe-s",
"fab fa-studiovinari",
"fab fa-stumbleupon",
"fab fa-stumbleupon-circle",
"fas fa-subscript",
"fas fa-subway",
"fas fa-suitcase",
"fas fa-sun", "far fa-sun",
"fab fa-superpowers",
"fas fa-superscript",
"fab fa-supple",
"fas fa-sync",
"fas fa-sync-alt",
"fas fa-table",
"fas fa-tablet",
"fas fa-tablet-alt",
"fas fa-tachometer-alt",
"fas fa-tag",
"fas fa-tags",
"fas fa-tasks",
"fas fa-taxi",
"fab fa-telegram",
"fab fa-telegram-plane",
"fab fa-tencent-weibo",
"fas fa-terminal",
"fas fa-text-height",
"fas fa-text-width",
"fas fa-th",
"fas fa-th-large",
"fas fa-th-list",
"fab fa-themeisle",
"fas fa-thermometer-empty",
"fas fa-thermometer-full",
"fas fa-thermometer-half",
"fas fa-thermometer-quarter",
"fas fa-thermometer-three-quarters",
"fas fa-thumbs-down", "far fa-thumbs-down",
"fas fa-thumbs-up", "far fa-thumbs-up",
"fas fa-thumbtack",
"fas fa-ticket-alt",
"fas fa-times",
"fas fa-times-circle", "far fa-times-circle",
"fas fa-tint",
"fas fa-toggle-off",
"fas fa-toggle-on",
"fas fa-trademark",
"fas fa-train",
"fas fa-transgender",
"fas fa-transgender-alt",
"fas fa-trash",
"fas fa-trash-alt", "far fa-trash-alt",
"fas fa-tree",
"fab fa-trello",
"fab fa-tripadvisor",
"fas fa-trophy",
"fas fa-truck",
"fas fa-tty",
"fab fa-tumblr",
"fab fa-tumblr-square",
"fas fa-tv",
"fab fa-twitch",
"fab fa-twitter",
"fab fa-twitter-square",
"fab fa-typo3",
"fab fa-uber",
"fab fa-uikit",
"fas fa-umbrella",
"fas fa-underline",
"fas fa-undo",
"fas fa-undo-alt",
"fab fa-uniregistry",
"fas fa-universal-access",
"fas fa-university",
"fas fa-unlink",
"fas fa-unlock",
"fas fa-unlock-alt",
"fab fa-untappd",
"fas fa-upload",
"fab fa-usb",
"fas fa-user", "far fa-user",
"fas fa-user-circle", "far fa-user-circle",
"fas fa-user-md",
"fas fa-user-plus",
"fas fa-user-secret",
"fas fa-user-times",
"fas fa-users",
"fab fa-ussunnah",
"fas fa-utensil-spoon",
"fas fa-utensils",
"fab fa-vaadin",
"fas fa-venus",
"fas fa-venus-double",
"fas fa-venus-mars",
"fab fa-viacoin",
"fab fa-viadeo",
"fab fa-viadeo-square",
"fab fa-viber",
"fas fa-video",
"fab fa-vimeo",
"fab fa-vimeo-square",
"fab fa-vimeo-v",
"fab fa-vine",
"fab fa-vk",
"fab fa-vnv",
"fas fa-volume-down",
"fas fa-volume-off",
"fas fa-volume-up",
"fab fa-vuejs",
"fab fa-weibo",
"fab fa-weixin",
"fab fa-whatsapp",
"fab fa-whatsapp-square",
"fas fa-wheelchair",
"fab fa-whmcs",
"fas fa-wifi",
"fab fa-wikipedia-w",
"fas fa-window-close", "far fa-window-close",
"fas fa-window-maximize", "far fa-window-maximize",
"fas fa-window-minimize",
"fas fa-window-restore", "far fa-window-restore",
"fab fa-windows",
"fas fa-won-sign",
"fab fa-wordpress",
"fab fa-wordpress-simple",
"fab fa-wpbeginner",
"fab fa-wpexplorer",
"fab fa-wpforms",
"fas fa-wrench",
"fab fa-xbox",
"fab fa-xing",
"fab fa-xing-square",
"fab fa-y-combinator",
"fab fa-yahoo",
"fab fa-yandex",
"fab fa-yandex-international",
"fab fa-yelp",
"fas fa-yen-sign",
"fab fa-yoast",
"fab fa-youtube"
]
}
```

and this is the gist also: https://gist.github.com/mohamdio/982653e3a8ae35f892f13c5ef0ef9b58

Comment: An updated version https://gist.github.com/mkwsra/fea6ce37cdc81aed31c454b83d0b2d1e

Answer (score 8):

Here is a snippet that works based on the loaded css. It assumes you have loaded the stylesheet with a name of font-awesome.css among other things but you could tweak this for your use. Theoretically, this will continue to work as future versions of font-awesome are released and new icons are added. That of course assume he keeps the css consistent over time.

```
var icons = $.map($.map(document.styleSheets, function(s) { 
    if(s.href && s.href.endsWith('font-awesome.css')) 
        return s; 
    return null; 
})[0].rules, function(r) { 
    if(r.cssText.indexOf('::before { content: ') > 0) 
        return r.cssText.substring(4,r.cssText.indexOf('::')); 
    return null; });
```

Comment: Great solution! This helps me a lot because I have my own font styleSheet which is changing all the time. I only changed one thing on your code: instead `[0].rules` I used `[0].cssRules` because `rules` is undefined to me.

Comment: Thanks used this to show a dropdown of fontawesome icons. Used a external stylesheet so had to download the stylesheet with ajax and add it to a temporary <styles> element and then use your code to extract the names. Works great and surprisingly fast..

Comment: `$(function () {
var rulesDef = $.map(document.styleSheets, function (s) {
     return s.href && (s.href.endsWith('font-awesome.min.css') || s.href.endsWith('font-awesome.css')) ? s : null
        });
            rulesDef.length <= 0 ? alert('Error, try loading font-awesome css reference.') : $(function () {
                var icons = $.map(rulesDef[0].rules, function (r) {
                    return r.cssText.indexOf('::before { content: ') > 0 ? r.cssText.substring(4, r.cssText.indexOf('::')) : null;
                });
                console.log(icons);
            });
      })`

Answer (score 8):

- Font Awesome Free's Cheatsheet: https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet
- Font Awesome Pro's Cheatsheet: https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet/pro

Below is the list of free icons class names as a list:

```
fa-500px
fa-accessible-icon
fa-accusoft
fa-acquisitions-incorporated
fa-adn
fa-adversal
fa-affiliatetheme
fa-airbnb
fa-algolia
fa-alipay
fa-amazon-pay
fa-amazon
fa-amilia
fa-android
fa-angellist
fa-angrycreative
fa-angular
fa-app-store-ios
fa-app-store
fa-apper
fa-apple-pay
fa-apple
fa-artstation
fa-asymmetrik
fa-atlassian
fa-audible
fa-autoprefixer
fa-avianex
fa-aviato
fa-aws
fa-bandcamp
fa-battle-net
fa-behance-square
fa-behance
fa-bimobject
fa-bitbucket
fa-bitcoin
fa-bity
fa-black-tie
fa-blackberry
fa-blogger-b
fa-blogger
fa-bluetooth-b
fa-bluetooth
fa-bootstrap
fa-btc
fa-buffer
fa-buromobelexperte
fa-buy-n-large
fa-buysellads
fa-canadian-maple-leaf
fa-cc-amazon-pay
fa-cc-amex
fa-cc-apple-pay
fa-cc-diners-club
fa-cc-discover
fa-cc-jcb
fa-cc-mastercard
fa-cc-paypal
fa-cc-stripe
fa-cc-visa
fa-centercode
fa-centos
fa-chrome
fa-chromecast
fa-cloudflare
fa-cloudscale
fa-cloudsmith
fa-cloudversify
fa-codepen
fa-codiepie
fa-confluence
fa-connectdevelop
fa-contao
fa-cotton-bureau
fa-cpanel
fa-creative-commons-by
fa-creative-commons-nc-eu
fa-creative-commons-nc-jp
fa-creative-commons-nc
fa-creative-commons-nd
fa-creative-commons-pd-alt
fa-creative-commons-pd
fa-creative-commons-remix
fa-creative-commons-sa
fa-creative-commons-sampling-plus
fa-creative-commons-sampling
fa-creative-commons-share
fa-creative-commons-zero
fa-creative-commons
fa-critical-role
fa-css3-alt
fa-css3
fa-cuttlefish
fa-d-and-d-beyond
fa-d-and-d
fa-dailymotion
fa-dashcube
fa-deezer
fa-delicious
fa-deploydog
fa-deskpro
fa-dev
fa-deviantart
fa-dhl
fa-diaspora
fa-digg
fa-digital-ocean
fa-discord
fa-discourse
fa-dochub
fa-docker
fa-draft2digital
fa-dribbble-square
fa-dribbble
fa-dropbox
fa-drupal
fa-dyalog
fa-earlybirds
fa-ebay
fa-edge-legacy
fa-edge
fa-elementor
fa-ello
fa-ember
fa-empire
fa-envira
fa-erlang
fa-ethereum
fa-etsy
fa-evernote
fa-expeditedssl
fa-facebook-f
fa-facebook-messenger
fa-facebook-square
fa-facebook
fa-fantasy-flight-games
fa-fedex
fa-fedora
fa-figma
fa-firefox-browser
fa-firefox
fa-first-order-alt
fa-first-order
fa-firstdraft
fa-flickr
fa-flipboard
fa-fly
fa-font-awesome-alt
fa-font-awesome-flag
fa-font-awesome-logo-full
fa-font-awesome
fa-fonticons-fi
fa-fonticons
fa-fort-awesome-alt
fa-fort-awesome
fa-forumbee
fa-foursquare
fa-free-code-camp
fa-freebsd
fa-fulcrum
fa-galactic-republic
fa-galactic-senate
fa-get-pocket
fa-gg-circle
fa-gg
fa-git-alt
fa-git-square
fa-git
fa-github-alt
fa-github-square
fa-github
fa-gitkraken
fa-gitlab
fa-gitter
fa-glide-g
fa-glide
fa-gofore
fa-goodreads-g
fa-goodreads
fa-google-drive
fa-google-pay
fa-google-play
fa-google-plus-g
fa-google-plus-square
fa-google-plus
fa-google-wallet
fa-google
fa-gratipay
fa-grav
fa-gripfire
fa-grunt
fa-guilded
fa-gulp
fa-hacker-news-square
fa-hacker-news
fa-hackerrank
fa-hips
fa-hire-a-helper
fa-hive
fa-hooli
fa-hornbill
fa-hotjar
fa-houzz
fa-html5
fa-hubspot
fa-ideal
fa-imdb
fa-innosoft
fa-instagram-square
fa-instagram
fa-instalod
fa-intercom
fa-internet-explorer
fa-invision
fa-ioxhost
fa-itch-io
fa-itunes-note
fa-itunes
fa-java
fa-jedi-order
fa-jenkins
fa-jira
fa-joget
fa-joomla
fa-js-square
fa-js
fa-jsfiddle
fa-kaggle
fa-keybase
fa-keycdn
fa-kickstarter-k
fa-kickstarter
fa-korvue
fa-laravel
fa-lastfm-square
fa-lastfm
fa-leanpub
fa-less
fa-line
fa-linkedin-in
fa-linkedin
fa-linode
fa-linux
fa-lyft
fa-magento
fa-mailchimp
fa-mandalorian
fa-markdown
fa-mastodon
fa-maxcdn
fa-mdb
fa-medapps
fa-medium-m
fa-medium
fa-medrt
fa-meetup
fa-megaport
fa-mendeley
fa-microblog
fa-microsoft
fa-mix
fa-mixcloud
fa-mixer
fa-mizuni
fa-modx
fa-monero
fa-napster
fa-neos
fa-nimblr
fa-node-js
fa-node
fa-npm
fa-ns8
fa-nutritionix
fa-octopus-deploy
fa-odnoklassniki-square
fa-odnoklassniki
fa-old-republic
fa-opencart
fa-openid
fa-opera
fa-optin-monster
fa-orcid
fa-osi
fa-page4
fa-pagelines
fa-palfed
fa-patreon
fa-paypal
fa-penny-arcade
fa-perbyte
fa-periscope
fa-phabricator
fa-phoenix-framework
fa-phoenix-squadron
fa-php
fa-pied-piper-alt
fa-pied-piper-hat
fa-pied-piper-pp
fa-pied-piper-square
fa-pied-piper
fa-pinterest-p
fa-pinterest-square
fa-pinterest
fa-playstation
fa-product-hunt
fa-pushed
fa-python
fa-qq
fa-quinscape
fa-quora
fa-r-project
fa-raspberry-pi
fa-ravelry
fa-react
fa-reacteurope
fa-readme
fa-rebel
fa-red-river
fa-reddit-alien
fa-reddit-square
fa-reddit
fa-redhat
fa-renren
fa-replyd
fa-researchgate
fa-resolving
fa-rev
fa-rocketchat
fa-rockrms
fa-rust
fa-safari
fa-salesforce
fa-sass
fa-schlix
fa-scribd
fa-searchengin
fa-sellcast
fa-sellsy
fa-servicestack
fa-shirtsinbulk
fa-shopify
fa-shopware
fa-simplybuilt
fa-sistrix
fa-sith
fa-sketch
fa-skyatlas
fa-skype
fa-slack-hash
fa-slack
fa-slideshare
fa-snapchat-ghost
fa-snapchat-square
fa-snapchat
fa-soundcloud
fa-sourcetree
fa-speakap
fa-speaker-deck
fa-spotify
fa-squarespace
fa-stack-exchange
fa-stack-overflow
fa-stackpath
fa-staylinked
fa-steam-square
fa-steam-symbol
fa-steam
fa-sticker-mule
fa-strava
fa-stripe-s
fa-stripe
fa-studiovinari
fa-stumbleupon-circle
fa-stumbleupon
fa-superpowers
fa-supple
fa-suse
fa-swift
fa-symfony
fa-teamspeak
fa-telegram-plane
fa-telegram
fa-tencent-weibo
fa-the-red-yeti
fa-themeco
fa-themeisle
fa-think-peaks
fa-tiktok
fa-trade-federation
fa-trello
fa-tripadvisor
fa-tumblr-square
fa-tumblr
fa-twitch
fa-twitter-square
fa-twitter
fa-typo3
fa-uber
fa-ubuntu
fa-uikit
fa-umbraco
fa-uncharted
fa-uniregistry
fa-unity
fa-unsplash
fa-untappd
fa-ups
fa-usb
fa-usps
fa-ussunnah
fa-vaadin
fa-viacoin
fa-viadeo-square
fa-viadeo
fa-viber
fa-vimeo-square
fa-vimeo-v
fa-vimeo
fa-vine
fa-vk
fa-vnv
fa-vuejs
fa-watchman-monitoring
fa-waze
fa-weebly
fa-weibo
fa-weixin
fa-whatsapp-square
fa-whatsapp
fa-whmcs
fa-wikipedia-w
fa-windows
fa-wix
fa-wizards-of-the-coast
fa-wodu
fa-wolf-pack-battalion
fa-wordpress-simple
fa-wordpress
fa-wpbeginner
fa-wpexplorer
fa-wpforms
fa-wpressr
fa-xbox
fa-xing-square
fa-xing
fa-y-combinator
fa-yahoo
fa-yammer
fa-yandex-international
fa-yandex
fa-yarn
fa-yelp
fa-yoast
fa-youtube-square
fa-youtube
fa-zhihu

fa-address-book
fa-address-card
fa-angry
fa-arrow-alt-circle-down
fa-arrow-alt-circle-left
fa-arrow-alt-circle-right
fa-arrow-alt-circle-up
fa-bell-slash
fa-bell
fa-bookmark
fa-building
fa-calendar-alt
fa-calendar-check
fa-calendar-minus
fa-calendar-plus
fa-calendar-times
fa-calendar
fa-caret-square-down
fa-caret-square-left
fa-caret-square-right
fa-caret-square-up
fa-chart-bar
fa-check-circle
fa-check-square
fa-circle
fa-clipboard
fa-clock
fa-clone
fa-closed-captioning
fa-comment-alt
fa-comment-dots
fa-comment
fa-comments
fa-compass
fa-copy
fa-copyright
fa-credit-card
fa-dizzy
fa-dot-circle
fa-edit
fa-envelope-open
fa-envelope
fa-eye-slash
fa-eye
fa-file-alt
fa-file-archive
fa-file-audio
fa-file-code
fa-file-excel
fa-file-image
fa-file-pdf
fa-file-powerpoint
fa-file-video
fa-file-word
fa-file
fa-flag
fa-flushed
fa-folder-open
fa-folder
fa-font-awesome-logo-full
fa-frown-open
fa-frown
fa-futbol
fa-gem
fa-grimace
fa-grin-alt
fa-grin-beam-sweat
fa-grin-beam
fa-grin-hearts
fa-grin-squint-tears
fa-grin-squint
fa-grin-stars
fa-grin-tears
fa-grin-tongue-squint
fa-grin-tongue-wink
fa-grin-tongue
fa-grin-wink
fa-grin
fa-hand-lizard
fa-hand-paper
fa-hand-peace
fa-hand-point-down
fa-hand-point-left
fa-hand-point-right
fa-hand-point-up
fa-hand-pointer
fa-hand-rock
fa-hand-scissors
fa-hand-spock
fa-handshake
fa-hdd
fa-heart
fa-hospital
fa-hourglass
fa-id-badge
fa-id-card
fa-image
fa-images
fa-keyboard
fa-kiss-beam
fa-kiss-wink-heart
fa-kiss
fa-laugh-beam
fa-laugh-squint
fa-laugh-wink
fa-laugh
fa-lemon
fa-life-ring
fa-lightbulb
fa-list-alt
fa-map
fa-meh-blank
fa-meh-rolling-eyes
fa-meh
fa-minus-square
fa-money-bill-alt
fa-moon
fa-newspaper
fa-object-group
fa-object-ungroup
fa-paper-plane
fa-pause-circle
fa-play-circle
fa-plus-square
fa-question-circle
fa-registered
fa-sad-cry
fa-sad-tear
fa-save
fa-share-square
fa-smile-beam
fa-smile-wink
fa-smile
fa-snowflake
fa-square
fa-star-half
fa-star
fa-sticky-note
fa-stop-circle
fa-sun
fa-surprise
fa-thumbs-down
fa-thumbs-up
fa-times-circle
fa-tired
fa-trash-alt
fa-user-circle
fa-user
fa-window-close
fa-window-maximize
fa-window-minimize
fa-window-restore
fa-ad
fa-address-book
fa-address-card
fa-adjust
fa-air-freshener
fa-align-center
fa-align-justify
fa-align-left
fa-align-right
fa-allergies
fa-ambulance
fa-american-sign-language-interpreting
fa-anchor
fa-angle-double-down
fa-angle-double-left
fa-angle-double-right
fa-angle-double-up
fa-angle-down
fa-angle-left
fa-angle-right
fa-angle-up
fa-angry
fa-ankh
fa-apple-alt
fa-archive
fa-archway
fa-arrow-alt-circle-down
fa-arrow-alt-circle-left
fa-arrow-alt-circle-right
fa-arrow-alt-circle-up
fa-arrow-circle-down
fa-arrow-circle-left
fa-arrow-circle-right
fa-arrow-circle-up
fa-arrow-down
fa-arrow-left
fa-arrow-right
fa-arrow-up
fa-arrows-alt-h
fa-arrows-alt-v
fa-arrows-alt
fa-assistive-listening-systems
fa-asterisk
fa-at
fa-atlas
fa-atom
fa-audio-description
fa-award
fa-baby-carriage
fa-baby
fa-backspace
fa-backward
fa-bacon
fa-bacteria
fa-bacterium
fa-bahai
fa-balance-scale-left
fa-balance-scale-right
fa-balance-scale
fa-ban
fa-band-aid
fa-barcode
fa-bars
fa-baseball-ball
fa-basketball-ball
fa-bath
fa-battery-empty
fa-battery-full
fa-battery-half
fa-battery-quarter
fa-battery-three-quarters
fa-bed
fa-beer
fa-bell-slash
fa-bell
fa-bezier-curve
fa-bible
fa-bicycle
fa-biking
fa-binoculars
fa-biohazard
fa-birthday-cake
fa-blender-phone
fa-blender
fa-blind
fa-blog
fa-bold
fa-bolt
fa-bomb
fa-bone
fa-bong
fa-book-dead
fa-book-medical
fa-book-open
fa-book-reader
fa-book
fa-bookmark
fa-border-all
fa-border-none
fa-border-style
fa-bowling-ball
fa-box-open
fa-box-tissue
fa-box
fa-boxes
fa-braille
fa-brain
fa-bread-slice
fa-briefcase-medical
fa-briefcase
fa-broadcast-tower
fa-broom
fa-brush
fa-bug
fa-building
fa-bullhorn
fa-bullseye
fa-burn
fa-bus-alt
fa-bus
fa-business-time
fa-calculator
fa-calendar-alt
fa-calendar-check
fa-calendar-day
fa-calendar-minus
fa-calendar-plus
fa-calendar-times
fa-calendar-week
fa-calendar
fa-camera-retro
fa-camera
fa-campground
fa-candy-cane
fa-cannabis
fa-capsules
fa-car-alt
fa-car-battery
fa-car-crash
fa-car-side
fa-car
fa-caravan
fa-caret-down
fa-caret-left
fa-caret-right
fa-caret-square-down
fa-caret-square-left
fa-caret-square-right
fa-caret-square-up
fa-caret-up
fa-carrot
fa-cart-arrow-down
fa-cart-plus
fa-cash-register
fa-cat
fa-certificate
fa-chair
fa-chalkboard-teacher
fa-chalkboard
fa-charging-station
fa-chart-area
fa-chart-bar
fa-chart-line
fa-chart-pie
fa-check-circle
fa-check-double
fa-check-square
fa-check
fa-cheese
fa-chess-bishop
fa-chess-board
fa-chess-king
fa-chess-knight
fa-chess-pawn
fa-chess-queen
fa-chess-rook
fa-chess
fa-chevron-circle-down
fa-chevron-circle-left
fa-chevron-circle-right
fa-chevron-circle-up
fa-chevron-down
fa-chevron-left
fa-chevron-right
fa-chevron-up
fa-child
fa-church
fa-circle-notch
fa-circle
fa-city
fa-clinic-medical
fa-clipboard-check
fa-clipboard-list
fa-clipboard
fa-clock
fa-clone
fa-closed-captioning
fa-cloud-download-alt
fa-cloud-meatball
fa-cloud-moon-rain
fa-cloud-moon
fa-cloud-rain
fa-cloud-showers-heavy
fa-cloud-sun-rain
fa-cloud-sun
fa-cloud-upload-alt
fa-cloud
fa-cocktail
fa-code-branch
fa-code
fa-coffee
fa-cog
fa-cogs
fa-coins
fa-columns
fa-comment-alt
fa-comment-dollar
fa-comment-dots
fa-comment-medical
fa-comment-slash
fa-comment
fa-comments-dollar
fa-comments
fa-compact-disc
fa-compass
fa-compress-alt
fa-compress-arrows-alt
fa-compress
fa-concierge-bell
fa-cookie-bite
fa-cookie
fa-copy
fa-copyright
fa-couch
fa-credit-card
fa-crop-alt
fa-crop
fa-cross
fa-crosshairs
fa-crow
fa-crown
fa-crutch
fa-cube
fa-cubes
fa-cut
fa-database
fa-deaf
fa-democrat
fa-desktop
fa-dharmachakra
fa-diagnoses
fa-dice-d20
fa-dice-d6
fa-dice-five
fa-dice-four
fa-dice-one
fa-dice-six
fa-dice-three
fa-dice-two
fa-dice
fa-digital-tachograph
fa-directions
fa-disease
fa-divide
fa-dizzy
fa-dna
fa-dog
fa-dollar-sign
fa-dolly-flatbed
fa-dolly
fa-donate
fa-door-closed
fa-door-open
fa-dot-circle
fa-dove
fa-download
fa-drafting-compass
fa-dragon
fa-draw-polygon
fa-drum-steelpan
fa-drum
fa-drumstick-bite
fa-dumbbell
fa-dumpster-fire
fa-dumpster
fa-dungeon
fa-edit
fa-egg
fa-eject
fa-ellipsis-h
fa-ellipsis-v
fa-envelope-open-text
fa-envelope-open
fa-envelope-square
fa-envelope
fa-equals
fa-eraser
fa-ethernet
fa-euro-sign
fa-exchange-alt
fa-exclamation-circle
fa-exclamation-triangle
fa-exclamation
fa-expand-alt
fa-expand-arrows-alt
fa-expand
fa-external-link-alt
fa-external-link-square-alt
fa-eye-dropper
fa-eye-slash
fa-eye
fa-fan
fa-fast-backward
fa-fast-forward
fa-faucet
fa-fax
fa-feather-alt
fa-feather
fa-female
fa-fighter-jet
fa-file-alt
fa-file-archive
fa-file-audio
fa-file-code
fa-file-contract
fa-file-csv
fa-file-download
fa-file-excel
fa-file-export
fa-file-image
fa-file-import
fa-file-invoice-dollar
fa-file-invoice
fa-file-medical-alt
fa-file-medical
fa-file-pdf
fa-file-powerpoint
fa-file-prescription
fa-file-signature
fa-file-upload
fa-file-video
fa-file-word
fa-file
fa-fill-drip
fa-fill
fa-film
fa-filter
fa-fingerprint
fa-fire-alt
fa-fire-extinguisher
fa-fire
fa-first-aid
fa-fish
fa-fist-raised
fa-flag-checkered
fa-flag-usa
fa-flag
fa-flask
fa-flushed
fa-folder-minus
fa-folder-open
fa-folder-plus
fa-folder
fa-font-awesome-logo-full
fa-font
fa-football-ball
fa-forward
fa-frog
fa-frown-open
fa-frown
fa-funnel-dollar
fa-futbol
fa-gamepad
fa-gas-pump
fa-gavel
fa-gem
fa-genderless
fa-ghost
fa-gift
fa-gifts
fa-glass-cheers
fa-glass-martini-alt
fa-glass-martini
fa-glass-whiskey
fa-glasses
fa-globe-africa
fa-globe-americas
fa-globe-asia
fa-globe-europe
fa-globe
fa-golf-ball
fa-gopuram
fa-graduation-cap
fa-greater-than-equal
fa-greater-than
fa-grimace
fa-grin-alt
fa-grin-beam-sweat
fa-grin-beam
fa-grin-hearts
fa-grin-squint-tears
fa-grin-squint
fa-grin-stars
fa-grin-tears
fa-grin-tongue-squint
fa-grin-tongue-wink
fa-grin-tongue
fa-grin-wink
fa-grin
fa-grip-horizontal
fa-grip-lines-vertical
fa-grip-lines
fa-grip-vertical
fa-guitar
fa-h-square
fa-hamburger
fa-hammer
fa-hamsa
fa-hand-holding-heart
fa-hand-holding-medical
fa-hand-holding-usd
fa-hand-holding-water
fa-hand-holding
fa-hand-lizard
fa-hand-middle-finger
fa-hand-paper
fa-hand-peace
fa-hand-point-down
fa-hand-point-left
fa-hand-point-right
fa-hand-point-up
fa-hand-pointer
fa-hand-rock
fa-hand-scissors
fa-hand-sparkles
fa-hand-spock
fa-hands-helping
fa-hands-wash
fa-hands
fa-handshake-alt-slash
fa-handshake-slash
fa-handshake
fa-hanukiah
fa-hard-hat
fa-hashtag
fa-hat-cowboy-side
fa-hat-cowboy
fa-hat-wizard
fa-hdd
fa-head-side-cough-slash
fa-head-side-cough
fa-head-side-mask
fa-head-side-virus
fa-heading
fa-headphones-alt
fa-headphones
fa-headset
fa-heart-broken
fa-heart
fa-heartbeat
fa-helicopter
fa-highlighter
fa-hiking
fa-hippo
fa-history
fa-hockey-puck
fa-holly-berry
fa-home
fa-horse-head
fa-horse
fa-hospital-alt
fa-hospital-symbol
fa-hospital-user
fa-hospital
fa-hot-tub
fa-hotdog
fa-hotel
fa-hourglass-end
fa-hourglass-half
fa-hourglass-start
fa-hourglass
fa-house-damage
fa-house-user
fa-hryvnia
fa-i-cursor
fa-ice-cream
fa-icicles
fa-icons
fa-id-badge
fa-id-card-alt
fa-id-card
fa-igloo
fa-image
fa-images
fa-inbox
fa-indent
fa-industry
fa-infinity
fa-info-circle
fa-info
fa-italic
fa-jedi
fa-joint
fa-journal-whills
fa-kaaba
fa-key
fa-keyboard
fa-khanda
fa-kiss-beam
fa-kiss-wink-heart
fa-kiss
fa-kiwi-bird
fa-landmark
fa-language
fa-laptop-code
fa-laptop-house
fa-laptop-medical
fa-laptop
fa-laugh-beam
fa-laugh-squint
fa-laugh-wink
fa-laugh
fa-layer-group
fa-leaf
fa-lemon
fa-less-than-equal
fa-less-than
fa-level-down-alt
fa-level-up-alt
fa-life-ring
fa-lightbulb
fa-link
fa-lira-sign
fa-list-alt
fa-list-ol
fa-list-ul
fa-list
fa-location-arrow
fa-lock-open
fa-lock
fa-long-arrow-alt-down
fa-long-arrow-alt-left
fa-long-arrow-alt-right
fa-long-arrow-alt-up
fa-low-vision
fa-luggage-cart
fa-lungs-virus
fa-lungs
fa-magic
fa-magnet
fa-mail-bulk
fa-male
fa-map-marked-alt
fa-map-marked
fa-map-marker-alt
fa-map-marker
fa-map-pin
fa-map-signs
fa-map
fa-marker
fa-mars-double
fa-mars-stroke-h
fa-mars-stroke-v
fa-mars-stroke
fa-mars
fa-mask
fa-medal
fa-medkit
fa-meh-blank
fa-meh-rolling-eyes
fa-meh
fa-memory
fa-menorah
fa-mercury
fa-meteor
fa-microchip
fa-microphone-alt-slash
fa-microphone-alt
fa-microphone-slash
fa-microphone
fa-microscope
fa-minus-circle
fa-minus-square
fa-minus
fa-mitten
fa-mobile-alt
fa-mobile
fa-money-bill-alt
fa-money-bill-wave-alt
fa-money-bill-wave
fa-money-bill
fa-money-check-alt
fa-money-check
fa-monument
fa-moon
fa-mortar-pestle
fa-mosque
fa-motorcycle
fa-mountain
fa-mouse-pointer
fa-mouse
fa-mug-hot
fa-music
fa-network-wired
fa-neuter
fa-newspaper
fa-not-equal
fa-notes-medical
fa-object-group
fa-object-ungroup
fa-oil-can
fa-om
fa-otter
fa-outdent
fa-pager
fa-paint-brush
fa-paint-roller
fa-palette
fa-pallet
fa-paper-plane
fa-paperclip
fa-parachute-box
fa-paragraph
fa-parking
fa-passport
fa-pastafarianism
fa-paste
fa-pause-circle
fa-pause
fa-paw
fa-peace
fa-pen-alt
fa-pen-fancy
fa-pen-nib
fa-pen-square
fa-pen
fa-pencil-alt
fa-pencil-ruler
fa-people-arrows
fa-people-carry
fa-pepper-hot
fa-percent
fa-percentage
fa-person-booth
fa-phone-alt
fa-phone-slash
fa-phone-square-alt
fa-phone-square
fa-phone-volume
fa-phone
fa-photo-video
fa-piggy-bank
fa-pills
fa-pizza-slice
fa-place-of-worship
fa-plane-arrival
fa-plane-departure
fa-plane-slash
fa-plane
fa-play-circle
fa-play
fa-plug
fa-plus-circle
fa-plus-square
fa-plus
fa-podcast
fa-poll-h
fa-poll
fa-poo-storm
fa-poo
fa-poop
fa-portrait
fa-pound-sign
fa-power-off
fa-pray
fa-praying-hands
fa-prescription-bottle-alt
fa-prescription-bottle
fa-prescription
fa-print
fa-procedures
fa-project-diagram
fa-pump-medical
fa-pump-soap
fa-puzzle-piece
fa-qrcode
fa-question-circle
fa-question
fa-quidditch
fa-quote-left
fa-quote-right
fa-quran
fa-radiation-alt
fa-radiation
fa-rainbow
fa-random
fa-receipt
fa-record-vinyl
fa-recycle
fa-redo-alt
fa-redo
fa-registered
fa-remove-format
fa-reply-all
fa-reply
fa-republican
fa-restroom
fa-retweet
fa-ribbon
fa-ring
fa-road
fa-robot
fa-rocket
fa-route
fa-rss-square
fa-rss
fa-ruble-sign
fa-ruler-combined
fa-ruler-horizontal
fa-ruler-vertical
fa-ruler
fa-running
fa-rupee-sign
fa-sad-cry
fa-sad-tear
fa-satellite-dish
fa-satellite
fa-save
fa-school
fa-screwdriver
fa-scroll
fa-sd-card
fa-search-dollar
fa-search-location
fa-search-minus
fa-search-plus
fa-search
fa-seedling
fa-server
fa-shapes
fa-share-alt-square
fa-share-alt
fa-share-square
fa-share
fa-shekel-sign
fa-shield-alt
fa-shield-virus
fa-ship
fa-shipping-fast
fa-shoe-prints
fa-shopping-bag
fa-shopping-basket
fa-shopping-cart
fa-shower
fa-shuttle-van
fa-sign-in-alt
fa-sign-language
fa-sign-out-alt
fa-sign
fa-signal
fa-signature
fa-sim-card
fa-sink
fa-sitemap
fa-skating
fa-skiing-nordic
fa-skiing
fa-skull-crossbones
fa-skull
fa-slash
fa-sleigh
fa-sliders-h
fa-smile-beam
fa-smile-wink
fa-smile
fa-smog
fa-smoking-ban
fa-smoking
fa-sms
fa-snowboarding
fa-snowflake
fa-snowman
fa-snowplow
fa-soap
fa-socks
fa-solar-panel
fa-sort-alpha-down-alt
fa-sort-alpha-down
fa-sort-alpha-up-alt
fa-sort-alpha-up
fa-sort-amount-down-alt
fa-sort-amount-down
fa-sort-amount-up-alt
fa-sort-amount-up
fa-sort-down
fa-sort-numeric-down-alt
fa-sort-numeric-down
fa-sort-numeric-up-alt
fa-sort-numeric-up
fa-sort-up
fa-sort
fa-spa
fa-space-shuttle
fa-spell-check
fa-spider
fa-spinner
fa-splotch
fa-spray-can
fa-square-full
fa-square-root-alt
fa-square
fa-stamp
fa-star-and-crescent
fa-star-half-alt
fa-star-half
fa-star-of-david
fa-star-of-life
fa-star
fa-step-backward
fa-step-forward
fa-stethoscope
fa-sticky-note
fa-stop-circle
fa-stop
fa-stopwatch-20
fa-stopwatch
fa-store-alt-slash
fa-store-alt
fa-store-slash
fa-store
fa-stream
fa-street-view
fa-strikethrough
fa-stroopwafel
fa-subscript
fa-subway
fa-suitcase-rolling
fa-suitcase
fa-sun
fa-superscript
fa-surprise
fa-swatchbook
fa-swimmer
fa-swimming-pool
fa-synagogue
fa-sync-alt
fa-sync
fa-syringe
fa-table-tennis
fa-table
fa-tablet-alt
fa-tablet
fa-tablets
fa-tachometer-alt
fa-tag
fa-tags
fa-tape
fa-tasks
fa-taxi
fa-teeth-open
fa-teeth
fa-temperature-high
fa-temperature-low
fa-tenge
fa-terminal
fa-text-height
fa-text-width
fa-th-large
fa-th-list
fa-th
fa-theater-masks
fa-thermometer-empty
fa-thermometer-full
fa-thermometer-half
fa-thermometer-quarter
fa-thermometer-three-quarters
fa-thermometer
fa-thumbs-down
fa-thumbs-up
fa-thumbtack
fa-ticket-alt
fa-times-circle
fa-times
fa-tint-slash
fa-tint
fa-tired
fa-toggle-off
fa-toggle-on
fa-toilet-paper-slash
fa-toilet-paper
fa-toilet
fa-toolbox
fa-tools
fa-tooth
fa-torah
fa-torii-gate
fa-tractor
fa-trademark
fa-traffic-light
fa-trailer
fa-train
fa-tram
fa-transgender-alt
fa-transgender
fa-trash-alt
fa-trash-restore-alt
fa-trash-restore
fa-trash
fa-tree
fa-trophy
fa-truck-loading
fa-truck-monster
fa-truck-moving
fa-truck-pickup
fa-truck
fa-tshirt
fa-tty
fa-tv
fa-umbrella-beach
fa-umbrella
fa-underline
fa-undo-alt
fa-undo
fa-universal-access
fa-university
fa-unlink
fa-unlock-alt
fa-unlock
fa-upload
fa-user-alt-slash
fa-user-alt
fa-user-astronaut
fa-user-check
fa-user-circle
fa-user-clock
fa-user-cog
fa-user-edit
fa-user-friends
fa-user-graduate
fa-user-injured
fa-user-lock
fa-user-md
fa-user-minus
fa-user-ninja
fa-user-nurse
fa-user-plus
fa-user-secret
fa-user-shield
fa-user-slash
fa-user-tag
fa-user-tie
fa-user-times
fa-user
fa-users-cog
fa-users-slash
fa-users
fa-utensil-spoon
fa-utensils
fa-vector-square
fa-venus-double
fa-venus-mars
fa-venus
fa-vest-patches
fa-vest
fa-vial
fa-vials
fa-video-slash
fa-video
fa-vihara
fa-virus-slash
fa-virus
fa-viruses
fa-voicemail
fa-volleyball-ball
fa-volume-down
fa-volume-mute
fa-volume-off
fa-volume-up
fa-vote-yea
fa-vr-cardboard
fa-walking
fa-wallet
fa-warehouse
fa-water
fa-wave-square
fa-weight-hanging
fa-weight
fa-wheelchair
fa-wifi
fa-wind
fa-window-close
fa-window-maximize
fa-window-minimize
fa-window-restore
fa-wine-bottle
fa-wine-glass-alt
fa-wine-glass
fa-won-sign
```

Comment: Also W3School have page for Font Awesome Free's Cheatsheet v4 and v5 : https://www.w3schools.com/icons/icons_reference.asp

Comment: For Font Awesome version 4 & 5 Free icon cheatsheet can be found here: SO has the word limit for the answers, my answer has already crossed the word limit. Below are the links for the Font Awesome version 4 & 5 Chearsheet:

Font Awesome version 4 Chearsheet:
https://fontawesome.com/v4/cheatsheet/

Font Awesome version 5 Chearsheet:
https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet/free/regular

Answer (score 7):

For future updates, copy paste the complete list from the cheatsheet (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) into an editor (notepad++ in my case). And do the following regular expression find & replace actions :

remove the special character at the begin and the characters between block quotes [&#xf042;]

```
find: ^.*(fa-[^\s]*).*
replace: \1
```

and if you want to wrap everything in an array:

```
find: ^.*(fa-[^\s]*).*
replace: "\1",
```

you only need to start the string with "[" and end it with "]" to make the array complete

Comment: Hi its exactly what I need, and I am trying this, but copying and pasting from the webpage cheatsheet into np++ makes it *one long line* and the find `^.`begin line does not work any longer. How can I strip it out to multiple lines and array initialize it?                                                          `List<string> faList = new List<string>()
         {
           "fa-1         "               ,
           "fa-bank "          ,
          ....
          };`         and also an `array of strings`

Answer (score 6):

Using PHP and the official icons.json file:

```
function fa_icons () {
    $content = file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/metadata/icons.json');
    $json = json_decode($content);
    $icons = [];

    foreach ($json as $icon => $value) {
        foreach ($value->styles as $style) {
            $icons[] = 'fa'.substr($style, 0 ,1).' fa-'.$icon;
        }
    }

    return $icons;
}
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => fab fa-500px
    [1] => fab fa-accessible-icon
    [2] => fab fa-accusoft
    [3] => fas fa-address-book
    [4] => far fa-address-book
    [5] => fas fa-address-card
    ...
```

Comment: The latest url is `'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/metadata/icons.json'`

Comment: I have changed the url to the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

**how to get Font Awesome Icons in a JSON object grouped by categories**

I made this to use with the excellent [jQuery fontIconPicker](https://codeb.it/fonticonpicker/)

*Done with with FA Version 5.0.6*

JSON result is available at https://gist.github.com/migliori/60154172ba0eea70e3c0dd4c3b5d82d0 for lazy people.

1. Navigate to https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&m=free
2. Paste this code in your browser console to grab the available categories and their icons.
   Wait about 2 minutes and it will return them into a JSON Object

   ```
   if(typeof endList == 'undefined') {
       var endList         = new Object();
       var catList         = document.getElementsByClassName('fa-ul')[2];
       var catListElements = catList.getElementsByTagName('li');
       var catListLength   = catListElements.length;
       console.log(catListLength);
       var i;

       var getIcons = function(el) {
           var classes = new Array();
           var name    = el.innerText;
           console.log(name);
           var icons   = document.getElementById('results-icons').getElementsByTagName('svg');
           for (var icon of icons) {
             var clazz = icon.getAttribute('data-prefix') + ' fa-' + icon.getAttribute('data-icon');
             classes.push(clazz);
           }
           console.log(classes);
           console.log('-----');
           endList[name] = classes;

           if(i + 1 < catListLength) {
               el.getElementsByClassName('relative')[0].click();
               i++;
               setTimeout(getCategory, 3000);
           } else {
               console.log(JSON.stringify(endList));
           }

           return;
       }

       var getCategory = function() {
           var el = catListElements[i];
           el.getElementsByClassName('relative')[0].click();
           setTimeout(function() {
               getIcons(el);
           }, 3000);
       }
   }
   i = 0;
   getCategory();
   ```

Answer (score 3):

1. fa 4: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/fa-4/src/icons.yml
2. fa 5: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/metadata/icons.json or https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/metadata/icons.yml

you can download and parse the file you need.

Comment: V5 now page not found

Answer (score 2):

One-liner using bash:

```sh
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/metadata/icons.json | jq 'keys'
```

In the format you want:

```sh
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/metadata/icons.json | jq 'keys' | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/  "/"fa-/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone would like to have Font awesome icons grouped just like in http://fontawesome.io/icons/. Paste this to JS console on icons screen of FA.

```
var allIcons = {};
$('#icons section:not(#new):not(#spinner)').each(function(key, item) {
    var name = $(item).attr('id');
    allIcons[name] = [];
    $(item).find('div a i').each(function(iconKey, icon) {
        allIcons[name].push($(icon).attr('class').substring(3));
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Park's answer is almost right.  However, sometimes there are more than one icon assigned to the same content for backwards compatibility.  This script will take that into consideration:

```
var icons = $.map($.map(document.styleSheets,
                function(s) {
                    if (s.href && s.href.endsWith('font-awesome.css'))
                        return s;
                    return null;
                })[0].rules,
            function(r) {
                var result = [];
                if (r.cssText.indexOf('::before { content: ') > 0) {
                    $.each(r.cssText.split(','),
                        function (i, item) {
                            result.push(item.split(':')[0].trim().substring(4));
                        });
                }
                return result;
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is more like [floribon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33794368/2251364) but in vanilla JS.

Head over to [Font Awesome Cheatsheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/), fire up the console and write.

```
var q=document.querySelectorAll('.row .col-md-4')
var names = []
for (var i=0;i<q.length;i++){
try{
names.push(q[i].innerHTML.match(/\s\sfa-.*\n/).toString().trim())
}
catch(e){}
}
names=names.filter(name => name.length)
console.log(names)
```

PS: This is subject to change when there's a change in DOM structure of the cheatsheet (unlikely) but you get the idea.

PPS: If the output is too large you can create a function to append a textarea at the bottom of the page so that you can easily copy.

```
append = function(names){
ns = names.join('\n')
txtarea=document.createElement("textarea")
txtarea.innerHTML=ns
document.body.appendChild(txtarea)
}
```

and replace the last line in the first code with

```
append(names)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://pastebin.com/JNtUcwyM - Complete list of complete class names with labels for version 5.0.1

if you retrieve a list of classes for a specific group you can add prefix and label then

```
var icons = []
brands.forEach(function(icon) {
      let element = {}
      element.className = "fab fa-" + icon;
      element.label = icon.replace(/-/g, ' ');
      icons.push(element);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(icons))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative 1:**

If you are using **JS setup** like `all.js` `brands.js` `regular.js` `solid.js`…

You can **get the list** from:

```
window.___FONT_AWESOME___
```

*Tested in FontAwesome **v5** and **v6***

---

**Alternative 2:**

**Get raw data** from their [Metadata folder](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/tree/master/metadata):

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/metadata/icons.json

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/master/metadata/icons.yml

---

**Alternative 3:**

Use their **API**

```
const query = `query allIcons {
    allIcons(
      version: "6.0.0-beta1"
      styles: ["solid"]
      page: 1
      perPage: 10000
      sort: "popularity"
    ) {
      iconCount
      icons {
        id
        label
        styles
        unicode
        membership { free pro }
      }
    }
  }
`
const data = fetch('https://api-canary.fontawesome.com', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify( { query } ),
}).then(r => r.json()).then(({ data }) => {
  console.log(data)
})
```

[image: FontAwesome API Result]

Answer (score 1):

STEP 1: Goto this page, https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet/free/solid

STEP 2: Open developer console tab,

```
const dts = document.querySelectorAll('dd.icon-name')
const fas = [...dts].map(i => i.textContent)
```

You might have to adjust the script above, because the layout of the web page might change in the future.

### Assemble

There's a lot of editor that can help you do multiple cursor operations. Ex. using Visual Studio Code, try ALT+Shift+Arrow to select rows so that you can append or delete to form new line of strings.

### List

```
[
    "ad",
    "address-book",
    "address-card",
    "adjust",
    "air-freshener",
    "align-center",
    "align-justify",
    "align-left",
    "align-right",
    "allergies",
    "ambulance",
    "american-sign-language-interpreting",
    "anchor",
    "angle-double-down",
    "angle-double-left",
    "angle-double-right",
    "angle-double-up",
    "angle-down",
    "angle-left",
    "angle-right",
    "angle-up",
    "angry",
    "ankh",
    "apple-alt",
    "archive",
    "archway",
    "arrow-alt-circle-down",
    "arrow-alt-circle-left",
    "arrow-alt-circle-right",
    "arrow-alt-circle-up",
    "arrow-circle-down",
    "arrow-circle-left",
    "arrow-circle-right",
    "arrow-circle-up",
    "arrow-down",
    "arrow-left",
    "arrow-right",
    "arrow-up",
    "arrows-alt",
    "arrows-alt-h",
    "arrows-alt-v",
    "assistive-listening-systems",
    "asterisk",
    "at",
    "atlas",
    "atom",
    "audio-description",
    "award",
    "baby",
    "baby-carriage",
    "backspace",
    "backward",
    "bacon",
    "bacteria",
    "bacterium",
    "bahai",
    "balance-scale",
    "balance-scale-left",
    "balance-scale-right",
    "ban",
    "band-aid",
    "barcode",
    "bars",
    "baseball-ball",
    "basketball-ball",
    "bath",
    "battery-empty",
    "battery-full",
    "battery-half",
    "battery-quarter",
    "battery-three-quarters",
    "bed",
    "beer",
    "bell",
    "bell-slash",
    "bezier-curve",
    "bible",
    "bicycle",
    "biking",
    "binoculars",
    "biohazard",
    "birthday-cake",
    "blender",
    "blender-phone",
    "blind",
    "blog",
    "bold",
    "bolt",
    "bomb",
    "bone",
    "bong",
    "book",
    "book-dead",
    "book-medical",
    "book-open",
    "book-reader",
    "bookmark",
    "border-all",
    "border-none",
    "border-style",
    "bowling-ball",
    "box",
    "box-open",
    "box-tissue",
    "boxes",
    "braille",
    "brain",
    "bread-slice",
    "briefcase",
    "briefcase-medical",
    "broadcast-tower",
    "broom",
    "brush",
    "bug",
    "building",
    "bullhorn",
    "bullseye",
    "burn",
    "bus",
    "bus-alt",
    "business-time",
    "calculator",
    "calendar",
    "calendar-alt",
    "calendar-check",
    "calendar-day",
    "calendar-minus",
    "calendar-plus",
    "calendar-times",
    "calendar-week",
    "camera",
    "camera-retro",
    "campground",
    "candy-cane",
    "cannabis",
    "capsules",
    "car",
    "car-alt",
    "car-battery",
    "car-crash",
    "car-side",
    "caravan",
    "caret-down",
    "caret-left",
    "caret-right",
    "caret-square-down",
    "caret-square-left",
    "caret-square-right",
    "caret-square-up",
    "caret-up",
    "carrot",
    "cart-arrow-down",
    "cart-plus",
    "cash-register",
    "cat",
    "certificate",
    "chair",
    "chalkboard",
    "chalkboard-teacher",
    "charging-station",
    "chart-area",
    "chart-bar",
    "chart-line",
    "chart-pie",
    "check",
    "check-circle",
    "check-double",
    "check-square",
    "cheese",
    "chess",
    "chess-bishop",
    "chess-board",
    "chess-king",
    "chess-knight",
    "chess-pawn",
    "chess-queen",
    "chess-rook",
    "chevron-circle-down",
    "chevron-circle-left",
    "chevron-circle-right",
    "chevron-circle-up",
    "chevron-down",
    "chevron-left",
    "chevron-right",
    "chevron-up",
    "child",
    "church",
    "circle",
    "circle-notch",
    "city",
    "clinic-medical",
    "clipboard",
    "clipboard-check",
    "clipboard-list",
    "clock",
    "clone",
    "closed-captioning",
    "cloud",
    "cloud-download-alt",
    "cloud-meatball",
    "cloud-moon",
    "cloud-moon-rain",
    "cloud-rain",
    "cloud-showers-heavy",
    "cloud-sun",
    "cloud-sun-rain",
    "cloud-upload-alt",
    "cocktail",
    "code",
    "code-branch",
    "coffee",
    "cog",
    "cogs",
    "coins",
    "columns",
    "comment",
    "comment-alt",
    "comment-dollar",
    "comment-dots",
    "comment-medical",
    "comment-slash",
    "comments",
    "comments-dollar",
    "compact-disc",
    "compass",
    "compress",
    "compress-alt",
    "compress-arrows-alt",
    "concierge-bell",
    "cookie",
    "cookie-bite",
    "copy",
    "copyright",
    "couch",
    "credit-card",
    "crop",
    "crop-alt",
    "cross",
    "crosshairs",
    "crow",
    "crown",
    "crutch",
    "cube",
    "cubes",
    "cut",
    "database",
    "deaf",
    "democrat",
    "desktop",
    "dharmachakra",
    "diagnoses",
    "dice",
    "dice-d20",
    "dice-d6",
    "dice-five",
    "dice-four",
    "dice-one",
    "dice-six",
    "dice-three",
    "dice-two",
    "digital-tachograph",
    "directions",
    "disease",
    "divide",
    "dizzy",
    "dna",
    "dog",
    "dollar-sign",
    "dolly",
    "dolly-flatbed",
    "donate",
    "door-closed",
    "door-open",
    "dot-circle",
    "dove",
    "download",
    "drafting-compass",
    "dragon",
    "draw-polygon",
    "drum",
    "drum-steelpan",
    "drumstick-bite",
    "dumbbell",
    "dumpster",
    "dumpster-fire",
    "dungeon",
    "edit",
    "egg",
    "eject",
    "ellipsis-h",
    "ellipsis-v",
    "envelope",
    "envelope-open",
    "envelope-open-text",
    "envelope-square",
    "equals",
    "eraser",
    "ethernet",
    "euro-sign",
    "exchange-alt",
    "exclamation",
    "exclamation-circle",
    "exclamation-triangle",
    "expand",
    "expand-alt",
    "expand-arrows-alt",
    "external-link-alt",
    "external-link-square-alt",
    "eye",
    "eye-dropper",
    "eye-slash",
    "fan",
    "fast-backward",
    "fast-forward",
    "faucet",
    "fax",
    "feather",
    "feather-alt",
    "female",
    "fighter-jet",
    "file",
    "file-alt",
    "file-archive",
    "file-audio",
    "file-code",
    "file-contract",
    "file-csv",
    "file-download",
    "file-excel",
    "file-export",
    "file-image",
    "file-import",
    "file-invoice",
    "file-invoice-dollar",
    "file-medical",
    "file-medical-alt",
    "file-pdf",
    "file-powerpoint",
    "file-prescription",
    "file-signature",
    "file-upload",
    "file-video",
    "file-word",
    "fill",
    "fill-drip",
    "film",
    "filter",
    "fingerprint",
    "fire",
    "fire-alt",
    "fire-extinguisher",
    "first-aid",
    "fish",
    "fist-raised",
    "flag",
    "flag-checkered",
    "flag-usa",
    "flask",
    "flushed",
    "folder",
    "folder-minus",
    "folder-open",
    "folder-plus",
    "font",
    "football-ball",
    "forward",
    "frog",
    "frown",
    "frown-open",
    "funnel-dollar",
    "futbol",
    "gamepad",
    "gas-pump",
    "gavel",
    "gem",
    "genderless",
    "ghost",
    "gift",
    "gifts",
    "glass-cheers",
    "glass-martini",
    "glass-martini-alt",
    "glass-whiskey",
    "glasses",
    "globe",
    "globe-africa",
    "globe-americas",
    "globe-asia",
    "globe-europe",
    "golf-ball",
    "gopuram",
    "graduation-cap",
    "greater-than",
    "greater-than-equal",
    "grimace",
    "grin",
    "grin-alt",
    "grin-beam",
    "grin-beam-sweat",
    "grin-hearts",
    "grin-squint",
    "grin-squint-tears",
    "grin-stars",
    "grin-tears",
    "grin-tongue",
    "grin-tongue-squint",
    "grin-tongue-wink",
    "grin-wink",
    "grip-horizontal",
    "grip-lines",
    "grip-lines-vertical",
    "grip-vertical",
    "guitar",
    "h-square",
    "hamburger",
    "hammer",
    "hamsa",
    "hand-holding",
    "hand-holding-heart",
    "hand-holding-medical",
    "hand-holding-usd",
    "hand-holding-water",
    "hand-lizard",
    "hand-middle-finger",
    "hand-paper",
    "hand-peace",
    "hand-point-down",
    "hand-point-left",
    "hand-point-right",
    "hand-point-up",
    "hand-pointer",
    "hand-rock",
    "hand-scissors",
    "hand-sparkles",
    "hand-spock",
    "hands",
    "hands-helping",
    "hands-wash",
    "handshake",
    "handshake-alt-slash",
    "handshake-slash",
    "hanukiah",
    "hard-hat",
    "hashtag",
    "hat-cowboy",
    "hat-cowboy-side",
    "hat-wizard",
    "hdd",
    "head-side-cough",
    "head-side-cough-slash",
    "head-side-mask",
    "head-side-virus",
    "heading",
    "headphones",
    "headphones-alt",
    "headset",
    "heart",
    "heart-broken",
    "heartbeat",
    "helicopter",
    "highlighter",
    "hiking",
    "hippo",
    "history",
    "hockey-puck",
    "holly-berry",
    "home",
    "horse",
    "horse-head",
    "hospital",
    "hospital-alt",
    "hospital-symbol",
    "hospital-user",
    "hot-tub",
    "hotdog",
    "hotel",
    "hourglass",
    "hourglass-end",
    "hourglass-half",
    "hourglass-start",
    "house-damage",
    "house-user",
    "hryvnia",
    "i-cursor",
    "ice-cream",
    "icicles",
    "icons",
    "id-badge",
    "id-card",
    "id-card-alt",
    "igloo",
    "image",
    "images",
    "inbox",
    "indent",
    "industry",
    "infinity",
    "info",
    "info-circle",
    "italic",
    "jedi",
    "joint",
    "journal-whills",
    "kaaba",
    "key",
    "keyboard",
    "khanda",
    "kiss",
    "kiss-beam",
    "kiss-wink-heart",
    "kiwi-bird",
    "landmark",
    "language",
    "laptop",
    "laptop-code",
    "laptop-house",
    "laptop-medical",
    "laugh",
    "laugh-beam",
    "laugh-squint",
    "laugh-wink",
    "layer-group",
    "leaf",
    "lemon",
    "less-than",
    "less-than-equal",
    "level-down-alt",
    "level-up-alt",
    "life-ring",
    "lightbulb",
    "link",
    "lira-sign",
    "list",
    "list-alt",
    "list-ol",
    "list-ul",
    "location-arrow",
    "lock",
    "lock-open",
    "long-arrow-alt-down",
    "long-arrow-alt-left",
    "long-arrow-alt-right",
    "long-arrow-alt-up",
    "low-vision",
    "luggage-cart",
    "lungs",
    "lungs-virus",
    "magic",
    "magnet",
    "mail-bulk",
    "male",
    "map",
    "map-marked",
    "map-marked-alt",
    "map-marker",
    "map-marker-alt",
    "map-pin",
    "map-signs",
    "marker",
    "mars",
    "mars-double",
    "mars-stroke",
    "mars-stroke-h",
    "mars-stroke-v",
    "mask",
    "medal",
    "medkit",
    "meh",
    "meh-blank",
    "meh-rolling-eyes",
    "memory",
    "menorah",
    "mercury",
    "meteor",
    "microchip",
    "microphone",
    "microphone-alt",
    "microphone-alt-slash",
    "microphone-slash",
    "microscope",
    "minus",
    "minus-circle",
    "minus-square",
    "mitten",
    "mobile",
    "mobile-alt",
    "money-bill",
    "money-bill-alt",
    "money-bill-wave",
    "money-bill-wave-alt",
    "money-check",
    "money-check-alt",
    "monument",
    "moon",
    "mortar-pestle",
    "mosque",
    "motorcycle",
    "mountain",
    "mouse",
    "mouse-pointer",
    "mug-hot",
    "music",
    "network-wired",
    "neuter",
    "newspaper",
    "not-equal",
    "notes-medical",
    "object-group",
    "object-ungroup",
    "oil-can",
    "om",
    "otter",
    "outdent",
    "pager",
    "paint-brush",
    "paint-roller",
    "palette",
    "pallet",
    "paper-plane",
    "paperclip",
    "parachute-box",
    "paragraph",
    "parking",
    "passport",
    "pastafarianism",
    "paste",
    "pause",
    "pause-circle",
    "paw",
    "peace",
    "pen",
    "pen-alt",
    "pen-fancy",
    "pen-nib",
    "pen-square",
    "pencil-alt",
    "pencil-ruler",
    "people-arrows",
    "people-carry",
    "pepper-hot",
    "percent",
    "percentage",
    "person-booth",
    "phone",
    "phone-alt",
    "phone-slash",
    "phone-square",
    "phone-square-alt",
    "phone-volume",
    "photo-video",
    "piggy-bank",
    "pills",
    "pizza-slice",
    "place-of-worship",
    "plane",
    "plane-arrival",
    "plane-departure",
    "plane-slash",
    "play",
    "play-circle",
    "plug",
    "plus",
    "plus-circle",
    "plus-square",
    "podcast",
    "poll",
    "poll-h",
    "poo",
    "poo-storm",
    "poop",
    "portrait",
    "pound-sign",
    "power-off",
    "pray",
    "praying-hands",
    "prescription",
    "prescription-bottle",
    "prescription-bottle-alt",
    "print",
    "procedures",
    "project-diagram",
    "pump-medical",
    "pump-soap",
    "puzzle-piece",
    "qrcode",
    "question",
    "question-circle",
    "quidditch",
    "quote-left",
    "quote-right",
    "quran",
    "radiation",
    "radiation-alt",
    "rainbow",
    "random",
    "receipt",
    "record-vinyl",
    "recycle",
    "redo",
    "redo-alt",
    "registered",
    "remove-format",
    "reply",
    "reply-all",
    "republican",
    "restroom",
    "retweet",
    "ribbon",
    "ring",
    "road",
    "robot",
    "rocket",
    "route",
    "rss",
    "rss-square",
    "ruble-sign",
    "ruler",
    "ruler-combined",
    "ruler-horizontal",
    "ruler-vertical",
    "running",
    "rupee-sign",
    "sad-cry",
    "sad-tear",
    "satellite",
    "satellite-dish",
    "save",
    "school",
    "screwdriver",
    "scroll",
    "sd-card",
    "search",
    "search-dollar",
    "search-location",
    "search-minus",
    "search-plus",
    "seedling",
    "server",
    "shapes",
    "share",
    "share-alt",
    "share-alt-square",
    "share-square",
    "shekel-sign",
    "shield-alt",
    "shield-virus",
    "ship",
    "shipping-fast",
    "shoe-prints",
    "shopping-bag",
    "shopping-basket",
    "shopping-cart",
    "shower",
    "shuttle-van",
    "sign",
    "sign-in-alt",
    "sign-language",
    "sign-out-alt",
    "signal",
    "signature",
    "sim-card",
    "sink",
    "sitemap",
    "skating",
    "skiing",
    "skiing-nordic",
    "skull",
    "skull-crossbones",
    "slash",
    "sleigh",
    "sliders-h",
    "smile",
    "smile-beam",
    "smile-wink",
    "smog",
    "smoking",
    "smoking-ban",
    "sms",
    "snowboarding",
    "snowflake",
    "snowman",
    "snowplow",
    "soap",
    "socks",
    "solar-panel",
    "sort",
    "sort-alpha-down",
    "sort-alpha-down-alt",
    "sort-alpha-up",
    "sort-alpha-up-alt",
    "sort-amount-down",
    "sort-amount-down-alt",
    "sort-amount-up",
    "sort-amount-up-alt",
    "sort-down",
    "sort-numeric-down",
    "sort-numeric-down-alt",
    "sort-numeric-up",
    "sort-numeric-up-alt",
    "sort-up",
    "spa",
    "space-shuttle",
    "spell-check",
    "spider",
    "spinner",
    "splotch",
    "spray-can",
    "square",
    "square-full",
    "square-root-alt",
    "stamp",
    "star",
    "star-and-crescent",
    "star-half",
    "star-half-alt",
    "star-of-david",
    "star-of-life",
    "step-backward",
    "step-forward",
    "stethoscope",
    "sticky-note",
    "stop",
    "stop-circle",
    "stopwatch",
    "stopwatch-20",
    "store",
    "store-alt",
    "store-alt-slash",
    "store-slash",
    "stream",
    "street-view",
    "strikethrough",
    "stroopwafel",
    "subscript",
    "subway",
    "suitcase",
    "suitcase-rolling",
    "sun",
    "superscript",
    "surprise",
    "swatchbook",
    "swimmer",
    "swimming-pool",
    "synagogue",
    "sync",
    "sync-alt",
    "syringe",
    "table",
    "table-tennis",
    "tablet",
    "tablet-alt",
    "tablets",
    "tachometer-alt",
    "tag",
    "tags",
    "tape",
    "tasks",
    "taxi",
    "teeth",
    "teeth-open",
    "temperature-high",
    "temperature-low",
    "tenge",
    "terminal",
    "text-height",
    "text-width",
    "th",
    "th-large",
    "th-list",
    "theater-masks",
    "thermometer",
    "thermometer-empty",
    "thermometer-full",
    "thermometer-half",
    "thermometer-quarter",
    "thermometer-three-quarters",
    "thumbs-down",
    "thumbs-up",
    "thumbtack",
    "ticket-alt",
    "times",
    "times-circle",
    "tint",
    "tint-slash",
    "tired",
    "toggle-off",
    "toggle-on",
    "toilet",
    "toilet-paper",
    "toilet-paper-slash",
    "toolbox",
    "tools",
    "tooth",
    "torah",
    "torii-gate",
    "tractor",
    "trademark",
    "traffic-light",
    "trailer",
    "train",
    "tram",
    "transgender",
    "transgender-alt",
    "trash",
    "trash-alt",
    "trash-restore",
    "trash-restore-alt",
    "tree",
    "trophy",
    "truck",
    "truck-loading",
    "truck-monster",
    "truck-moving",
    "truck-pickup",
    "tshirt",
    "tty",
    "tv",
    "umbrella",
    "umbrella-beach",
    "underline",
    "undo",
    "undo-alt",
    "universal-access",
    "university",
    "unlink",
    "unlock",
    "unlock-alt",
    "upload",
    "user",
    "user-alt",
    "user-alt-slash",
    "user-astronaut",
    "user-check",
    "user-circle",
    "user-clock",
    "user-cog",
    "user-edit",
    "user-friends",
    "user-graduate",
    "user-injured",
    "user-lock",
    "user-md",
    "user-minus",
    "user-ninja",
    "user-nurse",
    "user-plus",
    "user-secret",
    "user-shield",
    "user-slash",
    "user-tag",
    "user-tie",
    "user-times",
    "users",
    "users-cog",
    "users-slash",
    "utensil-spoon",
    "utensils",
    "vector-square",
    "venus",
    "venus-double",
    "venus-mars",
    "vest",
    "vest-patches",
    "vial",
    "vials",
    "video",
    "video-slash",
    "vihara",
    "virus",
    "virus-slash",
    "viruses",
    "voicemail",
    "volleyball-ball",
    "volume-down",
    "volume-mute",
    "volume-off",
    "volume-up",
    "vote-yea",
    "vr-cardboard",
    "walking",
    "wallet",
    "warehouse",
    "water",
    "wave-square",
    "weight",
    "weight-hanging",
    "wheelchair",
    "wifi",
    "wind",
    "window-close",
    "window-maximize",
    "window-minimize",
    "window-restore",
    "wine-bottle",
    "wine-glass",
    "wine-glass-alt",
    "won-sign",
    "wrench",
    "x-ray",
    "yen-sign",
    "yin-yang"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way, in case you only import the JS functionality from the libraries (tested with fontawesome 6.1.x):

```js
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid'
```

In such case the icon list is automatically available in the `window` namespace under `___FONT_AWESOME___`:

```js
const getAllFontAwesomeIcons = () => Object.keys(window.___FONT_AWESOME___.styles.fas)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the answer of @kjdion84 for the version 6 of font awesome with PHP

```
function getIcons(): array {
    $content = file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/6.x/metadata/icons.json');
    $json = json_decode($content);
    $icons = [];

    foreach ($json as $icon => $value) {
        foreach ($value->styles as $style) {
            $icons[] = "fa-$style fa-$icon";
        }
    }

    return $icons;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In latest font awesome 5.9 version we have around 1534 free icons, Divided into 3 categories

1. Solid icons
2. Regular icons
3. Brand icons

To use solid icons we need to add an additional class "fas" apart from Icon name

```
<i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>
```

Similarly to use Regular icons use "far" class name

```
<i class="far fa-address-book"></i>
```

To use brand icons use "fab"

```
<i class="fab fa-adobe"></i>
```

If you don't want to use default icon names by font awesome. You can use CSS content values to display icons as shown below

```
  .login::before {
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
  font-weight: 900;
  content: "\f007";
}
<span class="icons login"></span> Login
```

I have listed down complete 1534 free icons along with their CSS content values in this article

[1534 font awesome icons list,usage,css content values cheatsheet](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/font-awesome-icons-list-usage-css-content-values)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are able to download the Web toolkit, I created a Powershell script that pseudo-list all SVG files:

```
$File = "font-awesome.json" #this is the output
$BasePath = ".\fontawesome-pro-6.0.0-desktop\svgs\" #this is the svgs folder (trailing slash is important)

Add-Content -Path $File -Value "" #ensure output exists
Clear-Content -Path $File #truncates the output contents

$Items = Get-ChildItem -Path $BasePath -Filter *.svg -Recurse

Add-Content -Path $File -Value "[ " #creates an array
Add-Content -Path $File -Value "`"fa-$($Items[0].DirectoryName.Substring($BasePath.Length)) fa-$($Items[0].BaseName)`"" #renders first item without trailing comma
$Items | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { Add-Content -Path $File -Value ", `"fa-$($_.DirectoryName.Substring($BasePath.Length)) fa-$($_.BaseName)`"" } #renders rest of files
Add-Content -Path $File -Value " ]" #closes the array
```

Warning: script takes a while and generates +400KB file.

Answer (score 0):

you can always refer to the official Font Awesome website for the most up-to-date and comprehensive list.

Font Awesome provides an official website where you can explore and search for icons along with their respective class names: Font Awesome Icons

If you need the class names programmatically, you can use the official Font Awesome API: https://fontawesome.com/docs/apis/javascript/get-started

Answer (score -1):

Here's the list of all Fontawesome Icons":

[Fontawesome Gallery](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery)

[Here's another list of all font awesome icons](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/)

Code Sample:
`<i class="fa fa-rocket" width="50px" height="50px"></i>`

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getStyle() {
var index = 0; //index of stylesheet declare in head tage
var classesList = document.styleSheets[index].rules || document.styleSheets[index].cssRules
for (var x = 0; x < classesList.length; x++) 
{
if (classesList[x].cssText.match(/fa-/g) && classesList[x].cssText.match(/::/g)) 
{
var cc = classesList[x].cssText.split(' ')[0].split('::')[0];
console.log(cc);
}
}
};
getStyle();
</script>
```