# How to get all the icons from the fontawesome js library?

Tags: javascript, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I have included the font-awesome v5.12.1 library via CDN. Now, I want to get the list of `icons` or `icon text` to display as a select option. Is there any way to get the list of icons from the font-awesome js library as array so that I can display as dropdown.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze I want all the list of the icons as array so I can show a dropdown.

Comment: Check your browser request copy the JSON out of the right request.Or go over their [API](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/setup/getting-started)

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze The list of the icons are inside the javascript library. I have searched their library, there isn't a way to get all the icons list as array.

Comment: You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-blast to extract the icons as individual SVGs - you can then simply enumerate the filenames and if needed, load the relevant SVG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use their archive which has a file `metadata/icons.json` which provides that (and other useful) info and I've then used [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net) to build something similar to their list.
I'm not sure if this file can also be taken from CDN, but you may want to try https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/metadata/icons.json for the latest. (Caveat: could be different from CDN)

You may also want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992992/i-need-list-of-all-class-name-of-font-awesome) question and its answers which may help.

Comment: Hey, if you need list of all the pro icons of FAv5 visit my gist https://gist.github.com/cptiwari20/0fb100e26fef5292fc2cd0024d9cd4f5

Comment: and be sure to read this blog: https://blog.fontawesome.com/font-awesome-icon-metadata/  :)