# How to handle the error "Could not find icon"

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

I create the icon name dynamically, and sometimes it happens there is no corresponding icon in the library. Is there any way to catch the error and use the default icon name?

Comment: It would help if you posted some code.  You could use the `onerror` callback if you are talking about an `img` tag (https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/event_onerror.asp), but that would cause two requests.  Probably better to just have a large list of the images that you know you have, and if the icon isn't in that list, use the default one.

Comment: @user2740650 thanks, but Fontawesome uses svg not img tag. As for the list, I already thought about it but I wonder if there is any more elegant solution.

Comment: Ah, OK.  In that case this might help if you end up going the list route: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992992/i-need-list-of-all-class-name-of-font-awesome

Comment: Here's the direct link to the list: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/metadata/icons.json

Comment: @user2740650 the list is huge and I don't want to load it and search in it. I wonder if there is any util or function or any way inside Fontawesome just to see if some value is presented or not?

Comment: Maybe https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/javascript-api/methods/findicondefinition?

Comment: @user2740650 This would probably work! I will try tomorrow and tell then if it works or not.

Comment: @user2740650 So, finally I was able to try your solution and should admin it works! Yay! So, if you want more points, please add an answer, and will check it as a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findIconDefinition` to look up the icon name like this:

```
// Set params with details of the icon you're looking up depending
// on what variant you're using.
let params = {
   iconName: iconName,
   prefix: prefix
   // other entries as needed
};
if (!findIconDefinition(params)) {
    // Use default icon here.
}
```

Details for `findIconDefinition` are at https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/javascript-api/methods/findicondefinition